# What does "...this.props" mean in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What does `{...this.props}` mean in this code?

```
<div {...this.props} style={{ height: `100%`, }}
```

Comment: duplicate, check answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-in-react-do/41640566#41640566

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `{...variable}` syntax is called "spread attributes".

What this does is, basically, it takes every property of `this.props` (or any other passed variable) and applies them to the element.

Example:

```
props = {className: 'big', href: 'http://example.com'};

<a {...props} />
// the above line is equal to the following
<a className="big" href="http://example.com" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be the **spread operator** (three dots) that are setting you off? :)

[What does the three dots in react do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-in-react-do)

**Edit:** To elaborate, you're probably looking at a JSX template? Each property will in fact be a CSS property for your *style* attribute in the resulting HTML. Also, the spread operator makes it so that all properties within **this.props** get expanded, i.e. the same thing as if each property in **this.props** was explicitly output in the template.

Comment: @Zhao Yi, Taking code form http://stackoverflow.com/a/31049016/1589444 `var component = <Component {...jsonboject} />;` so in class definition of `Component` if you do `console.log(this.props)` in `render` function, it is like passing and array with different name, and access all keys of array directly form name variable in argument, like here `this.props` .

Answer (score 1):

{...this.props} means all of the props of current component. Let say you have object a and object b in props than {...this.props} means both a and b. You can pass all of your current component's props to another component by using this.