# Dynamic attributes on a react component element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a dynamic as possible app. So I thought why not build elements from just passing a json object to it.

I have this:

```
[
    {
        key: 1,
        element: 'input',
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'Jamie is'
    },
    {
        key: 2,
        element: 'input',
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'Jamie is Not'
    },
    {
        key: 3,
        element: 'input',
        type: 'password',
        placeholder: 'Jamie is'
    }
]
```

Each element from the array will get passed to my elements, so instead of having to define each attribute I'd like to just make sure I pass the correct attributes and have it build on the flu.

All hell breaks loose when I do this:

```
const input = React.createClass ({
    render() {
        let data = this.props.data;
        return (
            <input placeholder={data.placeholder} /> //current
            <input {data} /> //desired
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that is the best idea, but being that I'm not aware of your full requirements, here we go. To make this work, you could try doing `{...data}` instead of `{data}` in the `<input/>` element. However, custom attributes have certain reservations. Please refer to [this section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#custom-html-attributes) of the React documentation for more information. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-in-react-do) is some more information about what the three dots (...) are for.

Answer (score 0):

The custom `input` component with the `data` prop seems weird and messy to me.

It's pretty easy to build elements dynamically if you just look at what Babel compiles `<input foo={bar} />` to. Given your array of data all you have to do is

```
var inputs = data.map(
  ({element, ...props}) => React.createElement(element, props)
);
```