# Get first key and element from object

Tags: javascript

Let me know if you can take the first key and the first value set by an object as you can do with an array.

```
var a = [1,2];
var b = {1: "first", 2: "second"};

a[0] //1
b[0] //undefined
```

What would be the fastest way to get only first object key-val

```
{1: "first"}
```

EDIT

I need to have like result an object `result = {1: "first"};`

Thanks

Comment: `b['1']` this is your need.

Comment: @TomIsion that doesn't necessarily mean that's the first instance

Comment: b[Object.keys(b)[0]]; is what you need

Comment: @thatOneGuy Yep, you right

Comment: Possible duplicate. You may have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/1372621)

Comment: How do you define "first"? Because objects do NOT have an order in them. Do you want the key that is lexicographically lowest (1 < 2 < a < b) or something else?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var b = {1: "first", 2: "second"};

for (first in b) break;

console.log("Key : " + first);
console.log("Value : " + b[first]);
```

Comment: The iteration order with `for...in` is not guaranteed, so depending on the object and the browser, you may get different results.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for that and additionally [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method can be used if necessary.

```js
var b = {
  1: "first",
  2: "second"
};

console.log(
  b[Object.keys(b).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  })[0]]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no such thing like *first key* in Javascript objects. It's simply because their keys are unordered. If you actually want to get the smallest numeric key in an object, you can just directly get the value via its key like `b[1]`. If the smallest key is not given beforehand, you will need to use `Object.keys` for retrieving the key list, then get the smallest key from that list with `Math.min`.

```
var smallestKey = Math.min(...Object.keys(b));
var result = {[smallestKey]: b[smallestKey]};
```

Comment: If you wonder what those three dots are in the code above, check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31048953/1372621)

Answer (score -1):

Just another suggestion using the filter method:

```
const b = {1: "first", 2: "second"};
const firstKeyValue = Object.keys(b).filter( (a) => {
    return a
})

console.log(e.splice(0, 1))
```

Comment: What does that filter accomplish? At most, it's filtering out falsey values but that's it. It can literally be replaced with `.filter(Boolean)` and you'd get the same result back.