# JavaScript Syntax Explanation - return { ...state};

Tags: javascript

Trying to learn redux & react, currently digesting this tutorial: https://thinkster.io/tutorials/learn-redux/

Now, i found this code snippet

```
const defaultState = { checked: false };
const reducer = function(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE':
      return { ...state, checked: !state.checked };
  }
  return state;
};
const store = createStore(reducer);
```

I need an explanation of this line: `return { ...state, checked: !state.checked };`.

What does the `...state` do ? And is it a new feature of ECMA 2015 ??

**Update**

I don't think that this question is a duplicate of [What does the three dots in react do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-in-react-do)

The difference is that [What does the three dots in react do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-in-react-do) is about [JSX spread attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes), while my question is about [ECMAScript spread operator](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html).

Well, not trying to be defensive but i think those two are different.

But somehow i get the answer for my question in [What does the three dots in react do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-in-react-do)

Thanks to [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) for pointing me to the latter question :)

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, thanks for pointing me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-in-react-do, but i think that my question is actually different from that one. Updated my question for better explanation :)

Comment: Apologies - you were doing react and the spread operator does the same in JSX and ES6

Comment: `{ ...state, checked: !state.checked }` does the same as  `Object.assign({}, state, { checked: !state.checked })`