# What does mean '...props' in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

What means ...props? the code is:

```
export default class NavItem extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
}

render() {
    const { router, index, to, children, ...props } = this.props;
    let isActive = false;

    if (router.isActive('./', true) && index) {
        isActive = true
```

`children` I suppose that is the children of the actual element, but `...props` what does it mean?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the three dots in react do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-in-react-do)

Comment: `const { children, ...props } = this.props;` means assign props.children to children, all the rest values of this.props - to props.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`...` used in this context is referred to as ["the rest" parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), as in "the rest of them"

This line is using object [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax to assign from the object `this.props` new variables `router`, `index`, `to` and `children`, and everything else (the rest of them) in `this.props` into `props`

```
const { router, index, to, children, ...props } = this.props;
```

Here is another example of it's usage:

```
const bigBird = {height: 'tall', color: 'yellow', disposition: 'sunny'};
const {height, ...others} = bigBird;
//height == 'tall'
//others == {color: 'yellow', disposition: 'sunny'};
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a big help.