# What does return { ...state, } in this reducer exactly mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is `reducer_posts.js` from very simple blog react-redux app.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_POSTS, FETCH_ONE_POST, DELETE_POST } from '../actions/index';

export default function (state = {}, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case DELETE_POST:
      return _.omit(state, action.payload);

    case FETCH_ONE_POST:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.data._id]: action.payload.data };

    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, '_id');

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

`_.omit(state, action.payload)` is returning state without action.payload, so it is returning state without deleted post.

`_.mapKeys(action.payload.data, '_id')` creates an object with the same values as initial object, but new object has new key taken from `action.payload.data._id`

But I can't just get what in that code, this piece of syntax exactly does:

```
return {  ...state, [action.payload.data._id]: action.payload.data };
```

What does this line of code do? What does ... mean?

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the three dots in react do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-in-react-do)

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44245917/2545680) help? anything unclear?

Comment: @ Maximus  Thanks, I finally understood it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What does this line of code do?

Basically it does two things:

1. Adds old state properties to the new object by copying all enumerable properties from the `state` to the `{}`. Here is the quote form [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html):

> An alternative approach is to use the object spread syntax proposed
>   for the next versions of JavaScript which lets you use the spread
>   (...) operator to copy enumerable properties from one object to
>   another in a more succinct way. The object spread operator is
>   conceptually similar to the ES6 array spread operator.

2. Creates a new computed property with the key that is the result of evaluating `action.payload.data._id` and sets its value to the result of evaluating `action.payload.data`. Here is the quote from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also
>   supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression
>   in brackets [], that will be computed as the property name. This is
>   symmetrical to the bracket notation of the property accessor syntax,
>   which you might have used to read and set properties already.

Here is the example in pure JS:

```
const action = {payload: {data: {_id: 'some'}}};
const oldState = {a: '3'};
const newState = {...oldState, [action.payload.data._id]: action.payload.data}
console.log(newState); // {a: '3', some: {_id: 'some'}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally understood it!

Answer (score 1):

This line creates a brand new object based on all the available properties of current state and only updates the "action.payload.data._id" parameter.

as an example: When Redux is used as the application state management paradigm, to notify Redux about any changes in states, a new state object (reducer output) should be created to ensure the Redux that there is an actual state change occurred, (therefor the component will be re-rendered)