# How to save data in an array inside state in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `TextField` and `FlatButton` inside the `Dialog`. I want to save complete task list in an array which I defined in a state.

```
this.state = {
  open: false,
  todos: [{ id: -1, text: "", completed: false }],
  notetext: ""
};
```

I am able to get text of `TextField` from the state. I want to save task in an array on clicking of `FlatButton`. I have `handleCreateNote` function which is attached on tap on `FlatButton`.

I don't know what is the way to add task in an array. Can anyone help me what is the way in the react ?

```
const AppBarTest = () =>
  <AppBar
    title={strings.app_name}
    iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
    style={{ backgroundColor: colors.blue_color }}
  />;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    injectTapEventPlugin();
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      todos: [{ id: -1, text: "", completed: false }],
      notetext: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  handleCreateNote = () => {
    console.log(this.state.notetext);
  };

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <AppBarTest />
          <FloatingActionButton
            style={styles.fab}
            backgroundColor={colors.blue_color}
            onTouchTap={this.handleOpen}
          >
            <ContentAdd />
          </FloatingActionButton>
          <Dialog
            open={this.state.open}
            onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
            title={strings.dialog_create_note_title}
          >
            <TextField
              name="notetext"
              hintText="Note"
              style={{ width: "48%", float: "left", height: 48 }}
              defaultValue={this.state.noteVal}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />

            <div
              style={{
                width: "4%",
                height: "48",
                backgroundColor: "red",
                float: "left",
                visibility: "hidden"
              }}
            />

            <FlatButton
              label={strings.create_note}
              style={{ width: "48%", height: 48, float: "left" }}
              onTouchTap={this.handleCreateNote}
            />
          </Dialog>

        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create a copy of existing state array, then use `array.push` to add a new data, then use `setState` to update the state array value.

Like this:

```
handleCreateNote = () => {
    let todos = [...this.state.todos];   //creating the copy

    //adding new data
    todos.push({
        id: /*unique id*/,
        text: this.state.notetext,
        completed: false
    });

    //updating the state value
    this.setState({todos});
};
```

Check this answer for details about "**...**"  -->   [What do these three dots in React do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do)

MDN: [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

**Update:**

Instead of spread operator you can also use `slice()`, that will also return a new array, **the key point is we need to create a copy of state array** (before doing any change) by using any method.

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}];

let b = [...a];

console.log('b', b);
```

Comment: What . means here `[...this.state.todos];` ?

Comment: It's the destructuring assignment. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Actually it is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), which can be thought of as the opposite of destructuring assigment.

Comment: @ArneHugo Do you mean to convert props into an object ?

Comment: @Williams It can be used for multiple things. In this case, it's used to take every item in the array that `this.state.todos` points to, and add them to a new array. This way we avoid mutating the original array (like push does), to avoid confusion and reduce probability of bugs.

Comment: It is adding elements in an array, I tried `console.log(this.state.todos);` just after `this.setState({todos});` but it is not showing inserted element, it shows on next click which triggers same function. What could be the reason ?

Comment: reason is **setState is asynchronous**, answered this ques here, please check for full explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250

Answer (score 1):

you can use `concat` to create a new `array`:

```
this.setState({
    todos: [].Concat(this.state.todos, {id, text,  complete})
})
```