# Uncaught TypeError: this.state.Students.push is not a function and this.state.Students.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4

> What should i do?, i try many ways to solve this problem  but still
>   uncaught type error .push and .map is not function.Please help me solve this ,it will great honor for me.
>
> var InsertArray = React.createClass({
>       getInitialState: function () {
>           return {
>               Students: [],
>               Fname: '',
>               Lname: '',
>               Id: '',
>           }
>       },
>
> ```
> render: function () {
>     return (
>         <div>
>             Firstname:
>             <input type="text" onChange={this.handleFN} value={this.state.value} />
>             <br />
>             Lastname :
>             <input type="text" onChange={this.handleLN} value={this.state.value}/>
>             <br />
>             Student Id:
>             <input type="number" onChange={this.handleId} value={this.state.value} />
>             <hr />
>             <button type="Submit" onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
>             <button type="Submit" onClick={this.handleClickD}>Display</button>
>             <br />
>         </div>
>         );
> },
>
> handleFN : function (value) {
>     this.setState({
>         Fname: value
>     });
> },
>
> handleLn: function (value) {
>     this.setState({
>         Lname:value
>     });
> },
>
> handleId: function (value) {
>     this.setState({
>         Id: value
>     })
> },
> ```
>
> //this is where the data will be push into Student array by using
>   push.
>
> ```
> handleClick: function (e) {
>     e.preventDefault();
>     var student = {
>         Fname: this.state.Fname,
>         Lname: this.state.Lname,
>         Id   : this.state.Id
>     }
>     this.setState({
>         `Students: this.state.Students.push(student)`
>     });
> },
> ```
>
> //And this handleClickD will be read all the data inside array and
>   display.
>
> ```
> handleClickD: function (e) {
>     e.preventDefault();
>
>         <div>
>             <ul>`{this.state.Students.map(function (stud) {
>                     return (<li key={stud.Id}>{stud.Fname}{stud.Lname}`
>                 </li>)
>                 }
>                 )}
>             </ul>
>         </div>
> } });
> ```
>
> ReactDOM.render(,
>   document.getElementById('container'));

Comment: Are you ever initializing the state?

Comment: yea,i already initialized the state but still get caught error at map and push method.

Comment: I have 1 more problem map(). It doesn't display the data back after the user click display button .Please help me

Comment: I suggest creating a new question so you will get visibility on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explicit way of using push in the case would be like this

```
handleClick: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var student = {
        Fname: this.state.Fname,
        Lname: this.state.Lname,
        Id   : this.state.Id
    }

    this.state.Students.push(student)
    this.setState({
        Students: this.state.students
    });
},
```

But still, `concat()` is way better because its non verbose, and has fewer lines.

Answer (score 7):

Issue is, `array.push` will not return the final array, it will return the length of the array.

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

let b = a.push(10);

console.log('b = ', b);  //b = 7 not [1,2,3,4,5,6,10]
```

To solve you issue use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and put new value into array:

```
this.setState({
    Students: [...this.state.Students, student]
});
```

Check this for more details about spread operator: [What do these three dots in React do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do)

Answer (score 3):

use 'concat':

```
this.setState({Students: this.state.Students.concat(student)})
```

Comment: i try using concat and it works,thanks but if i want to use push how i'm gonna make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Array.push will return the new length of the array so after:

```
 this.setState({Students: this.state.Students.push(student)})
```

Students will be a number not an array.

Comment: could you explain more to be about that  because i'm new and i didn't understand much the way it work, thank you.

Comment: It means that the push function will work, but will just return the number of items inside the array, and not the actual results.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.push()` and `splice()` are mutable method.

**Why it's Effect react Set-state method Because of Immutability of the State.**

This reason doesn't use a mutable method in Set-state.
otherwise, you use the `concat()` and `slice()`
Ex:-

```
this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    newServiceStrings: this.state.newServiceStrings.concat(newServiceName)
})
```