# How do I apply my React styles inline with a ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm currently trying to add a side navbar slide in and out feature for my responsive site. I'm following the first animated example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp).

I was able to get it working first with `document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";`. However, I would prefer not manipulating the DOM using `document`. I would like to be using local state and updating that. I am using JavaScript inline styling. Here is what some of the code looks like working:

```
openNavbar = () => {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
};

<div style={styles.navbarMobile} onClick={this.openNavbar}>
  <NavSidebar/>
</div>

navbarMobile: {
  height: '100vh',
  width: '100%',
  position: 'fixed',
  zIndex: 11,
  top: '0',
  left: '-100%',
  overflowX: 'hidden',
  overflowY: 'hidden',
  transition: '1s',
  paddingRight: '15px',
  display: 'none',

  '@media (max-width: 992px)': {
    display: 'block',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
}
```

Now obviously I'm doing this a little different than the example. Rather than manipulating the width, I am manipulating the left position. It works and runs smoothly. However, I am now trying to implement some local state and changing the CSS according to the local state value. Here is what I have:

```
this.state = {
  navOpen: false
}

openNavbar = () => {
  this.setState({navOpen: true});
};

<div style={this.state.navOpen ? {left: 0} : {left: -100%}, styles.navbarMobile} onClick={this.openNavbar}>
  <NavSidebar/>
</div>

navbarMobile: {
  height: '100vh',
  width: '100%',
  position: 'fixed',
  zIndex: 11,
  top: '0',
  left: '-100%',
  overflowX: 'hidden',
  overflowY: 'hidden',
  transition: '1s',
  paddingRight: '15px',
  display: 'none',

  '@media (max-width: 992px)': {
    display: 'block',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
}
```

The main focus is on how to pass the ternary while also adding the other inline styling. By doing what I have above, all the css in `navbarMobile` gets applied. However, the ternary never runs. If I remove the `styles.navbarMobile` then the ternary works. Is there a way that I can run these two together? Any examples or ideas on how I should handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're setting up your `style` prop wrong. Since you have a comma, it acts as the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), so essentially, whatever the ternary is evaluated to, it's ignored and the `navbarMobile` style is *always* applied.  The ternary operator *is being evaluated*, it's just the comma operator *always evaluates to the rightmost operand*. Instead, use spread syntax like this:

```
<div style={{
  ...style.navbarMobile,
  left: this.state.navOpen ? 0 : '-100%'
}}>
```

This will take the styles in `navbarMobile` and copy them, then determine `left` based on `navOpen`. Read more about spread syntax in JSX [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do).

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Really well explained. I'm fairly new to javascript and es6 so it is nice to have things re-explained as I forget often haha. Thank you Andrew.

Comment: I do have one quick question. Do you know if the ternary gets run anytime the state changes? Or is it a one time evaluation?

Comment: @Nappstir It runs every time state changes because the element *is rerendered* on every state change (which means the `render` method is called every time state is changed).

Answer (score 0):

If you use React Hooks, you can do it a lot easier now.

```
<li style={{ textDecoration: isDone ? "line-through" : "none" }}>
        {props.text}
 </li>
```

Comment: How is your answer related to React hooks?