# Passing value dynamically in style object reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass background color dynamically and want to set in the component like this

```
<Paper style={circleStyle} zDepth={1} circle={true}> V </Paper>

const circleStyle = {
  ....
  background: '#00AA90',
  .....
};
```

Here in this example i want to pass background color dynamically how to do this ,I have other styles as well in `circleStyle` ?

PS: If i use `ClassName` in that case is also not working dynamic values, any idea ?

Comment: you mean you want to pass color along with circleStyle correct?

Comment: Have you tried using `var` instead of `const`? Is it a hoisting issue?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney variable is accessing fine, but the thing is i want to pass as parameter and set in object,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
style={{...circleStyle, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
```

Or

```
style={ Object.assign({}, circleStyle, {backgroundColor: 'red'}) }
```

Now style will get a new object that will contain `circleStyle` values as well as `backgroundColor`.

Check this snippet:

```js
let obj = {a: 1, b: 2};

let newObj = {...obj};      //equivalent to Object.assign({}, obj)

console.log('newObj = ', newObj);
```

Check this answer for more details about [Spread Operator (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

[What do these three dots in React do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do)

Comment: can you please tell what if i want to add style on the basis of media query  ? like we did using sepred operator will apply for all devices but if i want to apply some style using media query ?

Comment: not sure about media query, highly uncomfortable with css :)