# javascript three dots syntax

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm using [Vuetify](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify) for a vue app, in [this file](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/mixins/routable.js) I saw a very strange syntax which I can't find what it is

on line 38:

```
const data = {
    attrs: { disabled: this.disabled },
    class: this.classes,
    props: {},
    directives: [{
      name: 'ripple',
      value: this.ripple || false
    }],
    on: {
      ...(this.$listeners || {}),  // <<<---- here
      click: this.click
    }
  }
```

can anyone tell what is that three dots? any articles about this would be nice

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31048953

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: I would have just searched for "javascript three dots"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)! It grabs all the properties from the object.

In that example, it'll copy the object without mutating it.

Comment: It'll shallow copy, which has implications.

Answer (score 3):

it's a spread operator, which is used in ES6 for both objects and arrays in Javascript. Here, the returned value of (this.$listeners || {}) is extracted. This returned value, combined with click: this.click is added into another empty object, following the "on: "