# Does React property spread notation also pass on children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ellipsis

Does the React [*property spread notation*](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html#spread-attributes) in this `return` statement...

```
render() {
    return (
        <Alert {...this.props}</Alert>
    );
}
```

... also provide the `Alert` component with all the children passed to the current component which owns the above `render()` method?

Or would I explicitly have to provide the children like this?

```
render() {
    return (
        <Alert {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</Alert>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying, it turns out: **Yes, the children are also passed on**.

As stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31049016/2237467): whatever properties are in the object, they will be spread.