# I cannot find wath does ...state means in a reducer function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]

Comment: Before you know what ...state does here in reducer, know what the `...` operator is.

Comment: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usingobjectspreadoperator

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do

Comment: `state` is one of the arguments given to your reducer function, which in this case gets copied (spread operator is `...`) and a new array is returned with 1 new item in it

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar - And know that `...` [isn't an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934828/is-foo-an-operator-or-syntax/44934830#44934830).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why is it called spread operator then?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar - It isn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. Until today, I was taking it as operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the spread operator.

Documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax