# What is destructuring assignment and its uses?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, object-destructuring

I have been reading about [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) introduced in ES6.

What is the purpose of this syntax, why was it introduced, and what are some examples of how it might be used in practice?

Comment: does destructuring include the rest/spread operator?

Comment: @NickParsons to me these looks very closely related so i am considering them in this question, feel free to add those also in question

Comment: Also related: [What do these three dots in React do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953). Lots of useful answers on Destructuring, Spread syntax and Rest parameters

Comment: It's a great dupe-target reference question, and is highly indexed on Google, that's good enough for me. (searching for destructuring-related syntax questions to link to where the question doesn't contain "destructuring" is a pain)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### What is destructuring assignment ?

> The **destructuring assignment** syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

- [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

#### Advantages

- Makes code concise and more readable.
- We can easily avoid repeated destructing expression.

#### Some use cases

1. To get values in variable from Objects, array

   ```js
   let obj = { 'a': 1,'b': {'b1': '1.1'}}
   let {a,b,b:{b1}} = obj
   console.log('a--> ' + a, '\nb--> ', b, '\nb1---> ', b1)

   let obj2 = { foo: 'foo' };
   let { foo: newVarName } = obj2;
   console.log(newVarName);

   let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   let [first, second, ...rest] = arr
   console.log(first, '\n', second, '\n', rest)


   // Nested extraction is possible too:
   let obj3 = { foo: { bar: 'bar' } };
   let { foo: { bar } } = obj3;
   console.log(bar);
   ```
2. To change only desired property in an object

   ```js
   let arr = [{a:1, b:2, c:3},{a:4, b:5, c:6},{a:7, b:8, c:9}]

   let op = arr.map( ( {a,...rest}, index) => ({...rest,a:index+10}))

   console.log(op)
   ```
3. To extract values from parameters into standalone variables

   ```js
   // Object destructuring:
   const fn = ({ prop }) => {
     console.log(prop);
   };
   fn({ prop: 'foo' });


   console.log('------------------');


   // Array destructuring:
   const fn2 = ([item1, item2]) => {
     console.log(item1);
     console.log(item2);
   };
   fn2(['bar', 'baz']);


   console.log('------------------');


   // Assigning default values to destructured properties:

   const fn3 = ({ foo="defaultFooVal", bar }) => {
     console.log(foo, bar);
   };
   fn3({ bar: 'bar' });
   ```
4. To get dynamic keys value from object

   ```js
   let obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
   let key = 'c'
   let {[key]:value} = obj

   console.log(value)
   ```
5. To swap values

   ```js
   const b = [1, 2, 3, 4];
   [b[0], b[2]] = [b[2], b[0]]; // swap index 0 and 2

   console.log(b);
   ```
6. To get a subset of an object

   - [subset of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties/39333479):

     ```js
     const obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3},
           subset = (({a, c}) => ({a, c}))(obj); // credit to Ivan N for this function

     console.log(subset);
     ```
   - To get a [subset of an object using comma operator and destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54613019/9624435):

     ```js
     const object = { a: 5, b: 6, c: 7  };
     const picked = ({a,c}=object, {a,c})

     console.log(picked); // { a: 5, c: 7 }
     ```
7. To do array to object conversion:

   ```js
   const arr = ["2019", "09", "02"],
         date = (([year, day, month]) => ({year, month, day}))(arr);

   console.log(date);
   ```
8. [To set default values in function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54616597/9624435) (Read this answer for more info )

   ```js
   function someName(element, input, settings={i:"#1d252c", i2:"#fff", ...input}){
       console.log(settings.i);
       console.log(settings.i2);
   }

   someName('hello', {i: '#123'});
   someName('hello', {i2: '#123'});
   ```
9. To get properties such as `length` from an array, function name, number of arguments etc.

   ```js
   let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

   let {length} = arr;

   console.log(length);

   let func = function dummyFunc(a,b,c) {
     return 'A B and C';
   }

   let {name, length:funcLen} = func;

   console.log(name, funcLen);
   ```

Comment: I want to change key names while destructuring. I've an object from some API and the keys make no sense in readable code so I need to take them and make it better/readable:

`{message: {WeirdNameKey: 'Neil', MakesNoSense: 'Foo'}}`
// Wanted:
`const {name: WeirdNameKey, system: MakesNoSense} = message;`
I could have sworn I've done this, just to clean things up for use. But, it is not working for me. I just want to both extract and re-key.
I could have sworn I've done this before. Is possible?

Comment: @NeilGuyLindberg take a look at the first code snippet in the above answer, you can replace name of key like this, i.e `const {name: newName} = {name: 'some value'}`

Comment: Thank you @code-maniac. I see I was reversing the op. I just had to flip so I had: `{WeirdNameKey: name}`, and now the code reads well.

Answer (score 3):

**It is something like what you have can be extracted with the same variable name**

The destructuring assignment is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays or properties from objects into distinct variables. Let's get the month values from an array using destructuring assignment

```
var [one, two, three] = ['orange', 'mango', 'banana'];

console.log(one); // "orange"
console.log(two); // "mango"
console.log(three); // "banana"
```

and you can get user properties of an object using destructuring assignment,

```
var {name, age} = {name: 'John', age: 32};

console.log(name); // John
console.log(age); // 32
```

Answer (score 0):

The De-structured assignment of Javascript is probably an inspiration  drawn from Perl language.

This facilitates reuse by avoid writing getter methods or wrapper functions.

One best example that I found very helpful in particular was on reusing functions that return more data than what is required.

If there is a function that returns a list or an array or a json, and we are interested in only the first item of the list or array or json,
then we can simply use the de-structured assignment instead of writing a new wrapper function to extract the interesting data item.