# setting unset properties as default properties in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects, destructuring

I'm pretty new to JS and i'm trying to learn some basics in functions.
I'm facing a problem, I've created a function like this:

```
function someName (element, settings={i:"#1d252c", i2:"#fff"}) {
    .......
}
```

If i call the function as `someName(element)`. i and i2 retain their values, however

If i call it like `someName(element,{i:"#3acbda"})`, the value of i does change however the value of i2 is undefined,

So how do i assign the default value to a property when the settings object is no longer the default value.
So when i assign settings with only i, i2 is just the default value "#fff" and not undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **Object spread operator** `...` to enrich your options with default settings

```js
function someName(element, options){
    const settings = {i:"#aaa", i2:"#fff", ...options};
    console.log(settings)
}

// let's test
someName(null, {i:"#000"});
```

which is my preferred.  Alternatively you could also use a third argument:

```js
function someName(element, options, settings={i:"#aaa", i2:"#fff", ...options}){
    console.log(settings)
}

// let's test
someName(null, {i:"#000"});
```

In case you don't want to, or find clumbersome to always have to use the `settings` Object reference (like `settings.i`, `settings.i2` etc), you can use **Object unpacking** - and go directly for the propertyName:

```js
function someName(element, options ){
    const {i="#aaa", i2="#fff"} = options; 
    console.log( i, i2 );
}

// let's test
someName(null, {i:"#000"});
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use ***one extra variable at second place and at third place you can destructure.***( if you don't want to explicitly define inside function )

```js
function someName(element, input,settings={i:"#1d252c", i2:"#fff",...input}){
    console.log(settings.i)
    console.log(settings.i2)
}

someName('hello', {i:'#123'})
someName('hello', {i2:'#123'})
```

***On side note:-***  while using above trick you need to be sure that you're always passing one less parameter in function call than we define in function.

You can also define settings inside function and destructure

```js
function someName(element, input){
  const settings={i:"#1d252c", i2:"#fff",...input}
    console.log(settings.i)
    console.log(settings.i2)
}

someName('hello', {i:'#123'})
someName('hello', {i2:'#123'})
```

Some more uses of destrcturing you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-what-are-its-uses)

Comment: The first part of your question explains why I was having trouble trying to setup my demo. I ended up with everything within the function (I rarely need defaults because I try to keep tight control of data). +1

Comment: @zer00ne happy to help mate. but `...` is really helpful. you can see more examples in the link i have added in post. i am currently trying to experiment with it as much as i can

Answer (score 2):

## [ES6 Destructuring Assignment - Default Values](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-default-values/)

ES6 allows us to assign default values to Objects and Arrays. Here's the syntax for the former:

> ```
> //Declare Object like we normally do
> const settings = {i1: "#eee", i2: "#333"}
>
> //Destructure Object and assign defaults
> const {i1:"#fff", i2:"#fff"} = settings
> ```

One important caveat, defaults only happen if a value is `undefined`.

### Demo

**Note:** Clicking the radio buttons changes the `settings` object, observe the console. You should see that the default values kick in when only one or none of the properties are explicitly given a value.

```js
const main = document.forms[0];

function changeSettings(e) {
  const ui = e.currentTarget.elements;
  const in0 = ui.i0;
  const in1 = ui.i1;
  const in2 = ui.i2;
  const in3 = ui.i3;

  let settings = {
    i1: "#333",
    i2: "#000"
  };

  if (in0.checked) {
    settings = {
      i1: "#333",
      i2: "#000"
    };
  } else if (in1.checked) {
    settings = {
      i1: "#333",
    };
  } else if (in2.checked) {
    settings = {
      i2: "#000"
    };
  } else if (in3.checked) {
    settings = {};
  }

  let {
    i1 = "DEFAULT i1",
    i2 = "DEFAULT i2"
  } = settings;

  console.log(i1);
  console.log(i2);
  console.log('=============');
};

main.onchange = changeSettings;
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form id='main'>

  i1: "#333", i2: "#000"<input id='i0' type='radio' name='rad'><br> i1: "#333"<input id='i1' type='radio' name='rad'> <br> i2: "#000"<input id='i2' type='radio' name='rad'> <br> {}
  <input id='i3' type='radio' name='rad'> <br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Destructuring Objects` property like this.

```js
function some(element, { i='#fff', i2='#ddd' }) {
    console.log('element', element);
    console.log('color1', i);
    console.log('color2', i2);
}


some('elementOne', {})
const settings1 = {
  i: '#ccc'
}
some('elementTwo', {...settings1});

const settings2 = {
  i2: '#bbb'
}
some('elementTwo', {...settings2});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define defaults in the body by using the logical `||` (or) operator (null coalescing):

```js
function someName(element, settings={i:"#1d252c", i2:"#fff"}){
  settings['i'] = settings['i'] || "#1d252c"; // set to the current of resort to default
  settings['i2'] = settings['i2'] || "#fff"; 
  
  console.log(settings);
}
someName("foo", {i:"#3acbda"})
```

The above will add the `i2` property if it doesn't exist already in the `settings` argument and set it to `#fff`

Comment: Something like this can be done in argument list but with constrains also if you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/54616597/9624435