# Possible to destructure in JavaScript via bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, destructuring

This is not necessarily an issue, more a curiosity that came up via an ESLint error which led me to wonder if there was a better way that just disabling ESLint for this line.

Consider the code snippet below. ESLint will give an error if the [react/destructuring-assignment](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md) rule is enabled, preferring

`const { arrayToPrint } = myArrays` to `const arrayToPrint = myArrays[arrayName]`

My question is, and I haven't been able to find any reference to this so I'm guessing not, **is there a way to move `[arrayName]` to the lefthand side of the assignment to destructure without a reference to the actual object property?**

```js
const myArrays = {
  arrayOne: ['one'],
  arrayTwo: ['two'],
  arrayThree: ['three'],
}

const arrayPrinter = function arrayPrinter(arrayName) {
 const arrayToPrint = myArrays[arrayName]
  
  return arrayToPrint
}

console.log(arrayPrinter('arrayTwo'))
```

Comment: For clarity, you can replace `function arrayPrinter(arrayName)` by `arrayName => `

Comment: What's wrong with `let { arrayTwo } = myArrays; let arrayToPrint = arrayTwo;`?

Comment: @NinoFiliu nothing wrong with that at all, and it's probably a better pattern if I refactor my code, but the question still stands ;)

Comment: @NinoFiliu actually passing the array itself doesn't end up helping me. The use-case I have is updating the state of a parent component from a child, adding to one of several arrays based on a selection in the child component, so the child is telling the parent which value to add to which array (in parent state, and shared with other components).

Comment: @Ben you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-what-are-its-uses

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Destructuring can be done with [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring):

```
const { [arrayName]: arrayToPrint } = myArrays;
```

Comment: Also: `let {x: y} = {x: 10}; console.log(y); // 10`

Answer (score 0):

A simply way to do that is to use [`Object.entries(myArrays)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/entries) .

```
/* example: expected output of console.log(Object.entries(myArrays)[1]) is ["arrayTwo": Array ["two"]]
```