# How can I check if object contains a certain key?

Tags: javascript, object, key

This is my object `data`:

```
[{id:1, name:"Cat", category:{id:2, name:"Animals"}}]
```

I want to check if it contains the key `category`.

This is my approach:

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty("category")) {
console.log("data contains category");
}else {
  console.log("data does not contain category");
}
```

The output is:

> data does not contain category

Should be the opposite...

Comment: You have an array, not an object.  If you should have an object, you should be looking at the source of `data`.

Comment: @Devon. It must be an object, because if I `alert(data.toString());` this is the ouput: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: It's got `[ ]` around an object; it's an array with one object in it.

Comment: @Jarla, that's probably not the easiest way to see the data, use your console, not alerts.  Beyond that, you have an array of multiple objects from the looks of that, not a single object.   I think the problem is you're expecting a single object when you have an array of objects.  Whether the producer is wrong or whether the consumer's expectation is wrong is up to you to figure out.

Comment: @Devon Thank you, I am always confused with this question...is it an object or is it an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate your array.  So you can put the code inside a `forEach`

```js
let k = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Cat",
  category: {
    id: 2,
    name: "Animals"
  }
}]

k.forEach(function(data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty("category")) {
    console.log("data contains category");
  } else {
    console.log("data does not contain category");
  }
})
```

If you dont prefer to iterate you need to pass the index , since data is an array of object.

```js
let data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Cat",
  category: {
    id: 2,
    name: "Animals"
  }
}]


if (data[0].hasOwnProperty("category")) {
  console.log("data contains category");
} else {
  console.log("data does not contain category");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any object in your array matches a certain condition:

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Cat",
  category: {
    id: 2,
    name: "Animals"
  }
}];

var hasCategory = data.some(k => k.hasOwnProperty('category'));

if (hasCategory) {
  console.log("data contains category");
} else {
  console.log("data does not contain category");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through array elements. and you can [**destructure assignment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

```js
let arr = [{id:1, name:"Cat", category:{id:2, name:"Animals"}}]

arr.forEach(({category})=>{
  if (category !== undefined) {
   console.log("data contains category");
  }else {
   console.log("data does not contain category");
  }
})
```

Comment: Just a side note, if `category` is defined to `null`, `0`, or any other falsy value, your current code will display: _data does not contain category_. Maybe you can improve it changing the check condition to `category !== undefined`.

Comment: @CodeManiac You are welcome. I hope your down-vote gets reverted, was not my intention you get down-voted, sorry for that.

Comment: @Shidersz no problem mate :) down vote do not bother me. only motive is learning.

Answer (score 0):

That's an array with only one index, so you can do this using the operator `in`:

```
"category" in data[0] // That checks if the property "category" exists.
```

If you have more than one index, you should loop that array.

*The operator `in` also checks for inherited properties.*

```js
let data = [{id:1, name:"Cat", category:{id:2, name:"Animals"}}];
data.forEach((o, i) => console.log("Index:", i, " - Has category?:", "category" in o));
```