# get keys from object javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is what I have:

```
fields = [ { apple: 'red' }, { banana: 'yellow' } ]

fields.forEach(field => {
    // trying to get the key here
    if (Object.keys(field)[0] === 'apple')
        console.log('works!')
})
```

I want to ask is there a simple way for me to get the key? I feel I was making it too complicated by using

```
Object.key(field)[0]
```

add: I am just trying to get each key from this array of object and compare with a string.

Comment: An object can have any number of properties, so "the key" doesn't really make sense in general.

Comment: Can you add more context about what you want do with the keys? For example, if you're inspecting the keys and values, maybe you should use `Object.entries`

Comment: An array of objects with different keys is a code smell.

Comment: It would be better if it were something like `[{ fruit: 'apple', color: 'red'}, {fruit: 'banana', color: 'yellow'}]. Variable data should be in values, not keys.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I changed my design similar like what you said, it's way much easier to get the info I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `includes` to check if `apple` is within the array `Object.keys(field)`

```js
let fields = [{  apple: 'red'}, {  banana: 'yellow'}];

fields.forEach(field => {
  // trying to get the key here
  if (Object.keys(field).includes('apple'))
    console.log('works!')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [**destructuring assignment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses/54605288#54605288)

```js
let fields = [ { apple: 'red' }, { banana: 'yellow' } ]

fields.forEach( e => {
    let [key] = Object.keys(e)

    if (key === 'apple')
      console.log('works!')
})
```