# Capturing nested levels in JavaScript destructuring

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Does JavaScript destructuring have syntax to capture both an object and its content?

In other words, can I do the following completely in the function's arg list without the following `const` line?

```
f = (a) => {
  const {b} = a;
  console.log("I see:", a, "and", b);
}

f({b:42})

==> I see {b: 42} and 42
```

(FWIW: I'm thinking of something like `:as` in Clojure or ClojureScript).

Comment: Not in a parameter list, no - your solution in the body is fine. In declarations you can do `const outer = a, {b} = a;` and in nested destructuring you can do `const {outer, outer: {b}} = {outer: a};`

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can

```js
const f = (a, {b} = a ) => {
  console.log("I see:", a, "and", b);
}

f({b:42})
```

For more use cases of [destructuring assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses) you can see this

**On side note:-** Always keep one extra parameter than you in function definition than than your function call.

**Update** With this way you need not to worry about one extra parameter in function definition

```js
const f = (...z) => (a=z[0],{b}=z[0],...arguments) => {
  console.log("I see:", a, "and", b, z);
}

f({b:42},{b:32})()
```

You can try it with IIFE's too @bergi thanks for inputs.

```js
const f = (a, ...z) => (({b}) => {
  console.log("I see:", a, "and", b, z);
})(a);

f({b:42},{b:32})
```

Comment: cool trick but if you (by mistake) pass something as a second argument to the function everything breaks. It's safer to use destructuring in the function body.

Comment: @marzelin when you intend to do something like this, means you're always aware of what you're doing ? isn't it ?

Comment: @CodeManiac from my point of view doing something like this is just asking for trouble. People make mistakes unfortunately.

Comment: -1, this is not a comma operator.                                                        It's a delimiter between multiple parameters, and should absolutely not be used here.

Comment: No, there is no other way, but that doesn't make abusing default expressions any better.

Comment: @Bergi anyways this still uses default expression. but it is somewhat in more intended way. is this a better way https://jsfiddle.net/oac8w52z/

Comment: @CodeManiac If you go for IIFEs as a fill-in for let expressions, I do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/meusvptn/ :-)

Comment: @Bergi thanks for you valuable inputs. added your suggestion as well in answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way

```js
const f = (a, {b}=a) => {
  console.log("I see:", a, "and", b);
}

f({b:42})
```

The problem comes up when you need to pass more than one parameter.

```js
const f = (a, {b}=a) => {
  console.log("I see:", a, "and", b);
}

f({b:42},123)
```

Comment: -1, this is not a comma operator.                                                        It's a delimiter between multiple parameters, and should absolutely not be used here.