# Object destructuring in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I have a function which just return the part of existing object. in this case I am using Object destructuring but for this I need to repeat my code twice, one for retrieving properties and once for creating object like below.

```
function getPartlyState(obj) {
  const { x, y, z } = obj;
  return { x, y, z };
  //**OR**
  return { x: obj.x, y: obj.y, z: obj.z };
}
```

Is there any better way where I dont have to repeat my properties, something like below.

```
function getPartlyState(obj) {
  return { x, y,z } = obj;
}
```

Comment: Destructuring the parameters will help. If that's not enough, use a helper function instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses/54605288#54605288