# Return modified object in JavaScript (similar to lenses)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Similar to what lenses can do in functional languages, is there a way in JavaScript to return a new object identical to the original, but with some elements having been modified?

```
var myObject = {
  label: 'Table',
  options: ['legs'],
  params: {
    colour: 'red',
    feet: {
      colour: 'white',
      shape: 'round'
    }
  }
}

function newObject(obj) {
  // sought-after syntax here
  return obj({ params.colour = 'green', params.feet.shape = 'square' })
}

console.log(newObject(myObject))
{
  label: 'Table',
  options: ['legs'],
  params: {
    colour: 'green',
    feet: {
      colour: 'white',
      shape: 'square'
    }
  }
}
```

Note: `newObject()` returns a *new* object, without having affected the original in any shape or form.

Comment: Is it a plain object or is it going to be complex? Also, does it have any functions assigned to it or is it just primitives, arrays, and other objects?

Comment: There is no direct support for that in JavaScript but it would of course be possible to implement code to do  things like that.

Comment: That would be an object composed only of primitives, arrays and other objects

Comment: check immer or ramda or immutable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is destructuring assignment and its uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

Comment: JavaScript is functional enough that you can write your own lenses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using Spread Syntax

```js
var myObject = {
  label: 'Table',
  options: ['legs'],
  params: {
    colour: 'red',
    feet: {
      colour: 'white',
      shape: 'round'
    }
  }
}

function newObject(obj) {
  // sought-after syntax here
return ({...obj,params:{...obj.params,colour:"green",feet: {...obj.params.feet,shape:"square"}}})
}

console.log(newObject(myObject))
```

Comment: +1 for use of spread syntax. As a side note, there is a warning on this approach when using a lot of arguments, which may reach Javascript engine limit (which looks like depending of implementation, so from about 10 000 to 65 535 arguments). See [Spread_syntax#Spread_with_many_values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_with_many_values) and [apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions)

Comment: pretty much feels like native lenses support to me

Answer (score 1):

Without nesting that can easily be done using `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign({}, obj, { label: "New One" })
```

or using object spreading:

```
{ ...obj, label: "New One" }
```

to support nested objects / arrays you have to manually merge the objects recursively:

```
 function merge(target, changes) {
   const result = {};

   for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(target).concat(Object.entries(changes))) {
     if(Array.isArray(value)) {
       // TODO
     } else if(typeof value === "object") {
       result[key] = merge(result[key] || {}, value);
     } else {
       result[key] = value;
     }
   }

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way is:

```
let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObj))
```