# How overwrite and combine two objects in js?

Tags: javascript, object

I have two objects.

```
ObjectA = {name: 'Peter', age: 56, country: 'USA'}

ObjectB = {age: 34}
```

I want to update ObjectA to become

```
{name: 'Peter', age: 34, country: 'USA'}

if (ObjectB) {
    const newObject = ObjectA[Object.keys(ObjectB)[0]] === ....
}
```

What would be a better way to update ObjectA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is destructuring assignment and its uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

Comment: `{...objecta,...objectb}` will do the job

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**ES9/Regular Javascript**

```js
let object1 = {
 foo: 'foo'
}
let object2 = {
 bar: 'bar'
}

console.log({ ...object1, ...object2 })
console.log(Object.assign(object1, object2))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `Object.assign(ObjectA, ObjectB)`