# VueJs - Retrieve objects from array into new object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

Can anyone please help me find a way to return objects from an object array to concat all of them into a new object array with object names instead of keys.

```
array = [
  1: {
    cart: { fruits: {}, vegetables: {}, juices: {}}
  },
  2: {
    cart: { boxes: {}, tools: {}, bottles: {}}
  }
]
```

I am trying to get this specific output in **Vuejs** using methods and computed properties, But I am only able to get the output with keys as a normal array. I need the object name instead of keys.

Expected output

```
newArray = {
  cart: { fruits: {}, vegetables: {}, juices: {} boxes: {}, tools: {}, bottles: {}}
}
```

Comment: You have an invalid array

Comment: Can you please tell me where i went wrong ? so that i can correct it in the future.

Comment: An element in an array is not a name value pair. What you have inside `array = [1:{}, 2:{},]` is invalid. Instead, valid syntax is just `array = [{}, {}]`

Comment: Alright, I understand. I'll make sure to use proper syntax next time. But i think my point was made within the question as i got the solution i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and while iterating over the [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of every object in the array use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to collect they on the related key of the final expected output:

```js
let arr = [
  {
    cart: {fruits: {}, vegetables: {}, juices: {}},
    other: {foo: {}, bar: {}}
  },
  {
    cart: {boxes: {}, tools: {}, bottles: {}},
    other: {oof: {}, rab: {}}
  }
];

let res = arr.reduce((acc, obj) =>
{
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key =>
    {
        acc[key] = acc[key] || {};
        Object.assign(acc[key], obj[key]);
    });

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: I had to tweak it a little for it to work within my own code. But this was perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**destructuring assignment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses/54605288#54605288) and  merge object in desired format using key's.

```js
let array = [{cart: { fruits: {}, vegetables: {}, juices: {}}},{cart: { boxes: {}, tools: {}, bottles: {}}}]

let op = array.reduce( (op,inp) => {
  let key = Object.keys(inp)[0]
  op[key] = {...op[key], ...inp[key]}
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Your answer gave me the correct output within the console log but when i applied it using methods and computed property in Vuejs, The output turned out to be undefined. Must be probably something i missed to mention in the details. But, Thank you for the answer

Comment: @raghunath this is strange. if you used it properly it should work. maybe you may have missed adding something while copying.cross check once will be happy to help more

Comment: I copied the entire thing an used it within computed properties. The only change I did was setting the variables first and then assigning your code to it. But i still got an undefined output. But it worked in getting the output in the console log.