# How can I destructure an object property from an API call?

Tags: javascript

Considering this API [randomuser](https://randomuser.me/api/), how do I destructure the API to obtain the `results` property?

Comment: Which properties exactly are you trying to access via destructuring?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik The 'results' property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is destructuring assignment and its uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

Answer (score 1):

`{results : [{gender etc.}]}` then you will only get the properties enumerated

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would destruct the `results` prop from that endpoint:

```js
(async () => {
  const data = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')

  const { results } = await data.json()

  console.log(results) // returns `results` array from object
})()
```