# How to replace the key and value in array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript

I write a function `initMap(response){....}` .The response is an array of objects look like

```
In console :
(6)[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] 
0: {latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108"}
1: {latitude: "17.0504", longitude: "82.1659"}
2: {latitude: "17.1529", longitude: "82.2228"}
3: {latitude: "17.1621", longitude: "82.1921"}
4: {latitude: "17.0004", longitude: "82.2211"}
5: {latitude: "17.1235", longitude: "82.1926"}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want the output of an array like

```
 (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: {lat: 17.0009, lng: 82.2108}
  1: {lat: 17.0504, lng: 82.1659}
  2: {lat: 17.1529, lng: 82.2228}
  3: {lat: 17.1621, lng: 82.1921}
  4: {lat: 17.0004, lng: 82.2211}
  5: {lat: 17.1235, lng: 82.1926}
  length: 6
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

For getting this I tried in the way using replace

```
var eventlist = JSON.stringify(response);//Jsonresult
console.log(eventlist);

var eventstring = new String();
eventstring = eventlist.replace(/"/g, "");
events = eventstring.replace(/latitude/g, "lat").replace(/longitude/g, "lng");

 console.log(events);
```

While doing this I am getting the result in console as this way

```
[{lat:17.0009,lng:82.2108},{lat:17.0504,lng:82.1659},{lat:17.1529,lng:82.2228},{lat:17.1621,lng:82.1921},{lat:17.0004,lng:82.2211},{lat:17.1235,lng:82.1926}]
```

it look like as string but i need the output as

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: {lat: 17.0009, lng: 82.2108}
  1: {lat: 17.0504, lng: 82.1659}
  2: {lat: 17.1529, lng: 82.2228}
  3: {lat: 17.1621, lng: 82.1921}
  4: {lat: 17.0004, lng: 82.2211}
  5: {lat: 17.1235, lng: 82.1926}
  length: 6
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

How to do this please give me an idea about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.map` to iterate over the array and create a new object for every item:

```
const output = arr.map(({ latitude, longitude }) => ({
  lat: Number(latitude),
  lng: Number(longitude)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**destructuring assignment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses/54605288#54605288)

```js
let arr = [{latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108"},{latitude: "17.0504", longitude: "82.1659"},{latitude: "17.1529", longitude: "82.2228"},{latitude: "17.1621", longitude: "82.1921"},{latitude: "17.0004", longitude: "82.2211"},{latitude: "17.1235", longitude: "82.1926"}]

let op = arr.map(({latitude:lat, longitude:lng}) => ({lat:+lat, lng:+lng}))

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to recreate the object you want .Use `parseFloat` to covert sring to number

```js
var arr =[{latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108"},{latitude: "22.0009", longitude: "33.2108"}];
var res =  arr.map(a=> ({lat:parseFloat(a.latitude),lng:parseFloat(a.longitude)}))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there is not other better option than map. Another alternative with syntactical sugar-

```
var arr =[{latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108"},{latitude: "22.0009", longitude: "33.2108"}];
let result = arr.map(({ latitude, longitude })=>{
   return {
        lat: +latitude,
        lng: +longitude
   }
});
console.log(result);
```