# How do I parse a string to number while destructuring?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am trying to experiment around destructuring assignment. Now I have a case which I trying to cop up with destructuring itself.

For example, I have an input like this:

```
let input = {latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108"}
```

Where `latitude` and `longitude` key values are strings, but I want to parse them into a number while destructuring.

```js
let input = {latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108"}
let {latitude,longitude} = input

console.log(typeof latitude,typeof longitude)
```

I can see in [**babel repl**](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DYUwLgBAhgTjEF4IG9hTASzAVwCYgC4IAiARgHYA6ABloE5iAaCYAewDsBzLPQkgDgBMlQaWr9iAXwBQ00JFToe-Rmy7KQkxNDiygA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.3.4) that this takes a reference of an object and then access each key. So the above code is the same as:

```
"use strict";

 var arr = {
   latitude: "17.0009",
   longitude: "82.2108"
  };
 var latitude = arr.latitude,
     longitude = arr.longitude;
```

I want do something like using the destructuring syntax itself.

```
"use strict";

var arr = {
  latitude: "17.0009",
  longitude: "82.2108"
};
var latitude = Number(arr.latitude),
    longitude = Number(arr.longitude);
```

I am open to see some hacks too.

**Update**

I am able to come with up one hack with the `,` operator:

```js
let arr = {latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108"}

let {lat,lng} = ({latitude,longitude} = arr, ({lat:+latitude,lng:+longitude}))

console.log(typeof lat, typeof lng)
```

***On side note:-*** you must read 
[Moritz Roessler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55197490/9624435) this is hacky but contains good knowledge and information

Comment: `let input = {latitude: "17.0009"- 0, longitude: "82.2108"- 0}` While actually destructuring expressions aren't allowed only assignments. Before or after is allowed...

Comment: @zer00ne but i am not able to change input, for example take it as if it is coming from a third party.

Comment: How about input as a return of a function?

Comment: [take this as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193878/9624435) what i am looking to do is `{lat:+lat,lng:+lng}` to just `{lat,lng}` if i am able to destructure as well as change parse it to number

Comment: It looks like there's a type conversion on return

Comment: if the object is from a JSON string, the numbers can be converted in the [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter)

Comment: The update does not work if you specify `use strict` because `latitude` and `longitude` on the left side of the comma operator are implicit global variables.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Destructuring is just a nice way to unpack properties from objects and arrays and assign them to variables. As the trasnpiled code in the question suggests, any kind of operation is not possible.

One *hack* would be to create 2 more variables (which don't exist in `input`) and set the [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values) to the number equivalent of the previously destrucutred properties:

```js
let input = { latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108" }
let { latitude, longitude, lat = +latitude, long = +longitude } = input

console.log(typeof latitude, typeof longitude, typeof lat, typeof long)
```

The code *approximately* trasnpliles to this ([Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=AQ4GwUwF2BLA7ADgVxgXmAb3AQyrKZAEwgC5gAiARgHYA6ABiYE4KAacAe3gHMDiylABwAmOiKoMhFYAF8AUKHDQsufIRIcw3Phoha8wDAGowefpq68jwUzosQ5NhCihA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.3.4)):

```
var latitude = input.latitude,
    longitude = input.longitude,
    lat = input.lat === undefined ? +latitude : input.lat,
    long = input.long === undefined ? +longitude : input.long;
```

It's just exploiting the order in which the variables are created and assigned property values. Again, this works only if there are no `lat` or `long` properties in `input`. Otherwise, it will fail the ternary condition and `lat` will be set to `input.lat`.

---

Something like this would be much easier to read though:

```
let { latitude, longitude } = input;
let lat = +latitude, 
    long = +longitude;
```

OR

```
let [ lat, long ] = [ +latitude, +longitude ]
```

Comment: Thanks for idea mate :) yeah that's what i did but with `,` operator which is less readable

Comment: It'd be nice if we could just `let { +latitude } = …`

Comment: @Alhadis yeah it would be nice. but with current implementation it is not possible. cause when you do nested destructuring  `lat obj = {a:{b:{c:'some'}}};  let {a:{b:c}} = obj` it is same as `let c = obj.a.b.c` so if you use `+` some where in between you wont be able to access propeties

Comment: I love this one, it allows use of `const` as well.

Answer (score 12):

You could destructure the values, take an array of the values and map the a new data type of the value and assign this values back to the variables.

```js
let input = { latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108" },
    { latitude, longitude} = input;

[latitude, longitude] = [latitude, longitude].map(Number);

console.log(typeof latitude, latitude);
console.log(typeof longitude, longitude);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could have a **reusable function**, like this below:

```
const numberInputs = input =>
    Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, val) => {
        acc[val] = +input[val];
        return acc;
    }, {});
```

and then reuse it across...

Then do:

```
let {latitude,longitude} = numberInputs(input);

console.log(typeof latitude,typeof longitude) //number //number
```

and get `17.0009` and `82.2108` as numbers...

This way you keep **your original** object also and make a copy... so you have both original and copy of the object which has numbers as values...

Comment: Thanks for inputs. i am able to do it with out function using `,` operator and destructuring as you can see in the update. but i am having hard time to incorporate the in map `arr.map((/Here i am trying to do the same what i am able to do with comma operatore/) => {})` can you help in that ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible - no operations can be performed on a property during destructuring. If you use destructuring to extract a property into a variable, that variable will be `===` to the original property value.

(of course, you could transform the original object's values to Number prior to destructuring, but that's not the same thing)

Comment: Yeah that's kind of specified in question already. can i see some hacks around if you can come up with any ?

Answer (score 4):

Whilst you cannot perform type conversion within the destructuring expression itself, a possible alternative/workaround could be to destructure the properties within the arguments of a function, and then return an array with the new types within it.

For example, something like the following:

```js
const input = {latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108"}
const [lat, lng] = (({latitude:a, longitude:b}) => [+a, +b])(input);

console.log(typeof lat, typeof lng); // number number
```

However, for something like this, I wouldn't use destructuring and probably would resort to regular dot notation:

```js
const input = {latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108"}
const lat = +input.latitude;
const lng = +input.longitude;

console.log(typeof lat, typeof lng); // number number
```

Comment: Thanks for inputs. i am able to do it with out function using `,` operator and destructuring as you can see in the update. but i am having hard time to incorporate the in map arr.map((/Here i am trying to do the same what i am able to do with comma operatore/) => {}) can you help in that ?

Comment: Favor readability over hacky shortcuts - other users of your code and future you will thank you. Modern transpilers will do all the minification for you. So why not write in human readable form?

Comment: @CodeManiac hm, I couldn't come up with anything, but it seems like adiga has, I think their solution is what you're after

Comment: @NickParsons yeah mate his answer is cleaner than the `,` operator hack which i was doing

Answer (score 2):

There is a super hacky way of doing this using a getter defined on `String.prototype` as a helper function.

<sub>*(You probably don't want to do that)*</sub>

```js
Object.defineProperty (String.prototype, "asNumber",{
   get: function () { return +this}
});
let input = {latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108"}
let {latitude:{asNumber:latitude},
     longitude: {asNumber:longitude}} = input

console.log (latitude, longitude)
```

Let's break that down into simpler steps.

```
//Extending the `String` prototype means every string 
//will have access to the defined property  via 
//its prototype, so
String.prototype.foo = function () {return `${this}.foo\`} 
//means you can now call foo() like any other string method
"bar".foo() //"bar.foo"`

//A getter allows you to define a function that acts 
//as a property which will be executed upon access. 
let obj = {get getter () {console.log ('Hi');}}
obj.getter // Hi

//Combine those two and you can call functions by 
//accessing properties of strings. 
Object.defineProperty (String.prototype, "asNumber",{
   get: function () { return +this}
});

//Now that you have a property that is available at 
//every string - and make it execute a function; you 
//can convert a string to a number, simply by
//accessing a property
"42".asNumber //42

//To make that work with destructuring assignment, 
//you need to know about another handy feature. You 
//can assign destructured properties to a new 
//variable name.
let {a:b, b:a} = {a:'a', b:'b'};
a; //'b'
b; //'a'

//Since you can nest destructuring assignments, and 
//every string implicitly has a 'asNumber' property, 
//you can destructure that property as well. 

let {lat: {asNumber}} = {lat: "42"};
asNumber //42

//The last thing to know is, there's apparently 
//nothing wrong with using an existing variable as 
//new name for a destructured property. So you can 
//just use the `asNumber` property from the 
//prototype and assign it to the same variable  
//you destructured from the object.
let {lat: {asNumber: lat}} = {lat: "42"};
lat; //42
```

<sub>*There is nothing wrong with using the same name because only the last variable name will be introduced in the let block's scope*</sub>

Comment: Yes i don't want, but still love see some more explanation about it

Comment: @CodeManiac Sure (: glad to see people interested in the language. I added an explanation

Comment: Can't ask for any better explanation  :) this explanation contains so much of knowledge

Comment: But one thing i want to know `let {a : {b}} = {'a' : {'b': 'some value }}` here the nested destructuring captures `b` as `some value`. than how `let {lat: {asNumber}} = {lat: "42"};` is capturing ? or is it same as `let {lat:asNumber} = {lat} = {lat: "42"};` ?

Comment: @CodeManiac Yes, exactly, they are the same! (:

Comment: I have experimented enough [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses) but didn't knew this that i can use this nested one in such war. thanks mate :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using `lodash`, you can try this:

```
import { mapValues } from 'lodash';

const input = {latitude: "17.0009", longitude: "82.2108"}
const {latitude, longitude} = mapValues(input, Number);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably set things up so that each "object type" I cared about had a corresponding "parser type": an object with the same keys, but whose values are the appropriate parsing functions for each member.

Like so:

```js
"use strict";

var arr = {
    latitude: "17.0009",
    longitude: "82.2108"
};

function Parser(propParsers)
{
    this.propParsers = propParsers;
    this.parse = function (obj) {
        var result = {};
        var propParsers = this.propParsers;
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
            result[k] = propParsers[k](obj[k]);
        });
        return result;
    };
}

var parser = new Parser({
    latitude: Number,
    longitude: Number
});

let {latitude,longitude} = parser.parse(arr);
console.log(latitude);
console.log(longitude);
```