# How to parse a POINT object sent as string in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, string, object

I'm fetching some data from an API and the response includes the user location in longitude and latitude.

This is to render an icon on a map according to the user's coordinates

That's the JSON object:

```
{
  ...
  "lonlat": "POINT (-42.796763 -5.077056)",
}
```

I want to be able to parse this `POINT` object and get the value of latitude and longitude.

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just looking for help because I don't have any idea how to handle this kind of structure.

Comment: Does the API you're consuming not have a library to help you consume this `POINT(n n)` format? It's frankly kind of a whack way to send _generic_ coordinates, and looks like something preformatted for another consumer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace all values other then `space, digits and - and decimal` and then `trim leading and trailing whitespace` and then `split on space`

```
[^\d .-]
```

- [^\d .-] - Match anything except `digit, space, . and -`

```js
const data = {
  "lonlat": "POINT (-42.796763 -5.077056)"
};

let [lat,lng] = data.lonlat.replace(/[^\d .-]/g,'').trim().split(/\s+/)
console.log(lat);
console.log(lng);
```

Comment: Side-note: I particularly enjoy the elegant destructuring assignment.

Comment: @msanford than you will enjoy reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses) and [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55194118/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-number-while-destructuring)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to get the values, assuming they're always separated by a space.

```js
const data = {
  "lonlat": "POINT (-42.796763 -5.077056)"
};

const regex = /[A-Z]+\s\((-?\d+\.\d+)\s(-?\d+\.\d+)\)/;
const [, longitude, latitude] = data.lonlat.match(regex);
console.log(longitude);
console.log(latitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the characters between parenthesis first like the following way:

```js
var obj = {
  "lonlat": "POINT (-42.796763 -5.077056)",
}
var regExp = /\((.*?)\)/;
var lonlat = obj.lonlat.match(regExp)[1].split(' ');
console.log(lonlat);
```