# How to merge three different arrays by comparing with id? in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

Arrays:

```
 array1 = [{id:1, name:"raju"},{id:2, name:"ravi"},{id:4, name:"john"},{id:6, name:"jack"}];
 array2= [{id:1, degree:"b.com"},{id:3, degree:"b.a"},{id:4, degree:"c.a"},{id:5, degree:"horticulture"}];
 array3= [{id:1, age:20},{id:3, age:21},{id:6, age:27},{id:7, age:25}];
```

Required result is:

```
resultarray = [
    {id:1, name: "raju", degree:"b.com",age:20},
    {id:2, name: "ravi"},
    {id:3, degree:"b.a", age:21},
    {id:4, name:"john", degree:"c.a"},
    {id:5, degree:"horticulture"},
    {id:6, name:"jack", age:27},
    {id:7, age:25}
 ]
```

i have tried different functions and tried for two arrays but not able to merge the object which doesnt have id to compare..

Comment: hii, is there any alternative for object.values & object.keys.. because these two are not working in IE11.. is there any other way to get this output without using object.values & object.keys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**destructuring**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

Here idea is

- First merge all the arrays in one array.
- Now using reduce we create `id` as key in `op` object
- If `id` key is already there we merge the `inp` and `op[inp.id]`
- If id is not there we create a new key with value `inp`

```js
let array1 = [{id:1, name:"raju"},{id:2, name:"ravi"},{id:4, name:"john"},{id:6, name:"jack"}];
let array2= [{id:1, degree:"b.com"},{id:3, degree:"b.a"},{id:4, degree:"c.a"},{id:5, degree:"horticulture"}];
let array3= [{id:1, age:20},{id:3, age:21},{id:6, age:27},{id:7, age:25}];

let temp = [...array1,...array2,...array3]

let op = temp.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  op[inp.id] = op[inp.id] || inp
  op[inp.id] = {...op[inp.id],...inp}
  return op
},{})

console.log(Object.values(op))
```

Comment: can we keep this result array as a child to one parent id(another different id )

Comment: @PhaniKumarDevu i am unable to understand what you meant by above line, can you add explanation or some example ?

Comment: i mean there will one more id like{ UserID: 201, Userrating:resultarray} here UserID is parent and Userrating is child..

Comment: You can simply set `userrating`  key's value to `output` we are getting, `{userId: 201, userrating: Object.values(op)}` something like this

Comment: hii, is there any alternative for object.values & object.keys.. because these two are not working in IE11.. is there any other way to get this output without using object.values & object.keys

Comment: @PhaniKumarDevu you can use polyfill for that [Object.values ployfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js)

Answer (score 2):

a possible solution:

```js
let array1 = [{id:1, name:"raju"},{id:2, name:"ravi"},{id:4, name:"john"},{id:6, name:"jack"}];
let array2= [{id:1, degree:"b.com"},{id:3, degree:"b.a"},{id:4, degree:"c.a"},{id:5, degree:"horticulture"}];
let array3= [{id:1, age:20},{id:3, age:21},{id:6, age:27},{id:7, age:25}];

let resp = [].concat(array1, array2, array3).reduce((acc, ele) => {
        let obj = acc.find(x => x.id === ele.id);
        return obj ? (Object.keys(ele).forEach(x => obj[x] = ele[x]), acc) : acc.concat(ele);
    }, [])
    
console.log(resp)
```

Comment: can we keep this result array as a child to one parent id(another different id )

Comment: yeah, could you elaborate how do you pretend decide which one is parent?

Comment: i mean there will one more id like{ UserID: 201, Userrating:resultarray} here UserID is parent and Userrating is child..

Comment: hii, is there any alternative for object.values & object.keys.. because these two are not working in IE11.. is there any other way to get this output without using object.values & object.keys

Answer (score 1):

There will be better solutions than this, but this is what I've tried:

Merging the 3 arrays into one :

```
let array = [...array1, ...array2, ...array3]
```

Looping through the items and then putting the values to "object"

```
let object = {}    
array.forEach((item) => {
    object[item.id] = { ...object[item.id],...item}})
```

Final solution

```
result = Object.values(object)
```

object variable will contain

```
object = { '1': { id: 1, age: 20, name: 'raju', degree: 'b.com' },
      '2': { id: 2, name: 'ravi' },
      '3': { id: 3, age: 21, degree: 'b.a' },
      '4': { id: 4, degree: 'c.a', name: 'john' },
      '5': { id: 5, degree: 'horticulture' },
      '6': { id: 6, age: 27, name: 'jack' },
      '7': { id: 7, age: 25 } }
```

result variable will contain

```
result = [ { id: 1, age: 20, name: 'raju', degree: 'b.com' },
  { id: 2, name: 'ravi' },
  { id: 3, age: 21, degree: 'b.a' },
  { id: 4, degree: 'c.a', name: 'john' },
  { id: 5, degree: 'horticulture' },
  { id: 6, age: 27, name: 'jack' },
  { id: 7, age: 25 } ]
```

Comment: Oh by the i was adding this solution, 2 people have already solved and posted their answers :)

Comment: can we keep this result array as a child to one parent id(another different id )

Comment: yeah we can it is a list of objects. wait ill update the answer

Comment: i mean there will one more id like{ UserID: 201, Userrating:resultarray} here UserID is parent and Userrating is child..

Comment: hii, is there any alternative for object.values & object.keys.. because these two are not working in IE11.. is there any other way to get this output without using object.values & object.keys