# JS - Add a new property and value on one of the objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a list of objects

```
const array = [
    {club: "Club A", number: 12},
    {club: "Club B", number: 12}
]
```

I want to add a new property in one of the objects

```
member: ["a", "b"]
```

It would be

```
const newArray = [
    {club: "Club A", number: 12, member: ["a", "b"]},
    {club: "Club B", number: 12}
]
```

Tried with map

```
const newArray = array.map(obj => check if obj.club ==="Club A" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**object destrcturing**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

```js
const array = [{club: "Club A", number: 12},{club: "Club B", number: 12}]
let member = ["a", "b"]

const newArray = array.map(obj => obj.club === "Club A" ? {...obj,member} : obj)

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just assign the new property.

With a classic assignment:

```js
const
    array = [{ club: "Club A", number: 12 }, { club: "Club B", number: 12 }],
    member = ["a", "b"];
    
array.find(({ club }) => club === "Club A").member = member;

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const
    array = [{ club: "Club A", number: 12 }, { club: "Club B", number: 12 }],
    member = ["a", "b"];
    
Object.assign(array.find(({ club }) => club === "Club A"), { member });

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Object.assign in map

```js
const array = [
    {club: "Club A", number: 12},
    {club: "Club B", number: 12}
]

const member = {member: ["a", "b"]};

const newArray = array.map(obj => obj.club === 'Club A' ? Object.assign(obj, member) : obj);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the item you want to edit. Then just assign the property to it:

```js
const array = [
    {club: "Club A", number: 12},
    {club: "Club B", number: 12}
]

// find the correct item
let item = array.find(item => item.club == "Club A")
item.member =  ["a", "b"]

console.log(array)
```