# What is shorter notation for this in latest JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I've got this:

```
const id = speakerRec.id;
const firstName = speakerRec.firstName;
const lastName = speakerRec.lastName;
```

and I think there is something like this but can't remember it.

```
const [id, firstName, lastName] = speakerRec;
```

Comment: `{ }` not `[ ]` (in this case), [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is destructuring assignment and its uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `{}` for destructuring object properties:

```
const {id, firstName, lastName} = speakerRec;
```

`[]` is used for array destructuring:

```
const [one, two, three] = [1, 2, 3];
```

Demonstration:

```js
const speakerRec = {
  id: "mySpeaker",
  firstName: "Jack",
  lastName: "Bashford"
};

const { id, firstName, lastName } = speakerRec;

console.log(id);
console.log(firstName);
console.log(lastName);

const [one, two, three] = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(one);
console.log(two);
console.log(three);
```

Answer (score 6):

It's an object, so use object destructuring (not array destructuring):

```
const { id, firstName, lastName } = speakerRec;
```

Comment: Is there such a thing as array destructuring?

Comment: @Adelin https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring

Comment: And you can use object destructuring on arrays too, it's just a little awkward.