# How to convert arrow function into a regular function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrow-functions

I am trying to convert an arrow function into a regular function

this piece of code:

```
let rating = watchList.map( (item) => ({"title":item["Title"], "rating":item["imdbRating"]}) )
```

like so:

```
let rating = watchList.map( function (item) {
    "title":item["Title"], "rating":item["imdbRating"]
})
```

while I thought these two are equivalent, I am getting this message

> SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token, expected

Comment: `return {"title":item["Title"], "rating":item["imdbRating"]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are lacking `return`. When you pass in a custom function for the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, you will need to return a value for that function.

```
let rating = watchList.map(function(item) {
  return {"title":item["Title"], "rating":item["imdbRating"]};
})
```

Nonetheless, it is more useful to use the arrow functions, as arrow functions seems more concise, and allows you to access `this` within it.

Answer (score 4):

In arrow function any expression after `=>` become implicit return of function.

In regular functions you need to use `return` keyword.And also warp your properties in `{}`

```
let rating = watchList.map(function(item){
    return {"title":item["Title"], "rating":item["imdbRating"]};    
}
```

You can also shorten your code by using Parameter destructuring.

```
let rating = watchList.map(function({Title:title,imdbRating:rating}){
    return {"title":Title, "rating":imdbRating};    
}
```

Or you could name to properties while destuctruing.

```
let rating = watchList.map(function({Title:title,imdbRating:rating}){
    return {title,rating};  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**return**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) and you can also use [**shorthand notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) of object if you use [**destructuring**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

```
let rating = watchList.map(function({Title:title, imdbRating:rating}) {
  return {title,rating};
})
```