# es6 iterate through an array of objects with nested arrays and return a single array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given the following scenario, how can I return a single array?

```
let array = [{
    name: "name01", 
    arr: [
      {name: "inner01"}, 
      {name: "inner02"}, 
      {name: "inner03"}
    ]
  }, {
    name: "name02", 
    arr: [
      {name: "inner04"}, 
      {name: "inner05"}, 
      {name: "inner06"}
    ]
  }
]

let convo = array.map(item => {
  return {
    name: item.name,
    ...item.arr,
  };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3ng8dc2x/1/

I would like to get something like:

```
[
  {name: "name01"}, 
  {name: "inner01"}, 
  {name: "inner02"}, 
  {name: "inner03"},
  {name: "name02"},
  {name: "inner04"}, 
  {name: "inner05"}, 
  {name: "inner06"}
]
```

As always any and all direction is appreciated, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) might be a better option than map.

```js
let array = [{
    name: "name01", 
    arr: [
      {name: "inner01"}, 
      {name: "inner02"}, 
      {name: "inner03"}
    ]
  }, {
    name: "name02", 
    arr: [
      {name: "inner04"}, 
      {name: "inner05"}, 
      {name: "inner06"}
    ]
  }
]

let convo = array.reduce((a, {name, arr}) => a.concat([{name}], arr), []);
console.log(convo)
```

Comment: on side note:- And you missed adding `name` keys in output `name01` and `name02`

Comment: Because of the nature of my use case and the preference for concise code, this will work great!  Thanks!

...and thanks for all of the different views and directions to solve for this!

Answer (score 5):

If you are writing for the latest browsers and latest node, [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is perfect for this:

```js
let array = [{
    name: "name01", 
    arr: [
      {name: "inner01"}, 
      {name: "inner02"}, 
      {name: "inner03"}
    ]
  }, {
    name: "name02", 
    arr: [
      {name: "inner04"}, 
      {name: "inner05"}, 
      {name: "inner06"}
    ]
  }
]

let flat = array.flatMap(({name, arr}) => [{name}, ...arr])
console.log(flat)
```

Comment: just noticed, the result is missing `name01` and `name02`

Comment: And you missed adding `name` key's in output `name01` and `name02`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn it's a fair warning, but I think it's an overstatement to say MDN doesn't suggest using it. It just isn't supposed everywhere yet, but if it is supported where you need, it works well.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to combine [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and for every entry of the current inspected `object`, check the type to decide how to put the element on a new array:

```js
let array = [
  {
    name: "name01", 
    surname: "surname01", 
    arr: [{name: "inner01"}, {name: "inner02"}, {name: "inner03"}]
  },
  {
    name: "name02",
    surname: "surname02",  
    arr: [{name: "inner04"}, {name: "inner05"}, {name: "inner06"}]
  }
];

let res = array.reduce((acc, curr) =>
{
    Object.entries(curr).forEach(([k, v]) =>
    {
        if (typeof v === 'string')
            acc.push({[k]: v});
        else if (Array.isArray(v))
            acc.push(...v);
    });

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note, the previous is likely a generic solution, however, if you can trust on the structure of your objects, i.e, they all have a `name` property holding a `string` and an `array` on the property `arr`, then the code can be simplified:

```js
let array = [
  {
    name: "name01", 
    arr: [{name: "inner01"}, {name: "inner02"}, {name: "inner03"}]
  },
  {
    name: "name02", 
    arr: [{name: "inner04"}, {name: "inner05"}, {name: "inner06"}]
  }
];

let res = array.reduce(
    (acc, {name, arr}) => acc.concat([{name}, ...arr]),
    []
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [**destructuring assignment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

```js
let array = [{name: "name01", arr: [{name: "inner01"}, {name: "inner02"}, {name: "inner03"}]},
{name: "name02", arr: [{name: "inner04"}, {name: "inner05"}, {name: "inner06"}]}]

let op = array.reduce((op,{name,arr}) =>op.concat([{name}],arr),[])

console.log(op)
```