# Use destructuring assignment inside state

Tags: reactjs, eslint

```js
class BottomPanelProgramTabs extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    activeTab: this.props.children[0].props.label,
  };

...
```

ESLint want me to use destructuring assignment on

```js
this.props.children[0].props.label
```

any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is destructuring assignment and its uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this.
[For more reference about prefer-destructuring](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring)

```
class BottomPanelProgramTabs extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(){
        let [props] = this.props.children;
         state = {
          activeTab : props.label
         }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class BottomPanelProgramTabs extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  state = {
    activeTab: 'default label'
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {

    const [{ props: { label } }] = this.props.children;

    this.setState({
      activeTab: label || 'default label',
      ...
    })
  }

  ...
```

You can mix destructing by getting the first element with `[]` and get the props with `{}`.

**For example**:

using `[child]` will give us the first element in the array.

```js
const children = [{
    props: {
      label: 'Some label'
    }
  },
  {
    props: {
      label: 'Second label'
    }
  },

  ,
  {
    props: {
      label: 'another label'
    }
  }]
  
  const [child] = children;
  
  console.log(child);
```

to get `props` we can continue mixing our destruction by adding `[ {props} ]` which returns `props` object.

```js
const children = [{
    props: {
      label: 'Some label'
    }
  },
  {
    props: {
      label: 'Second label'
    }
  },

  ,
  {
    props: {
      label: 'another label'
    }
  }]
  
  const [ {props} ] = children;
  
  console.log(props);
```

to get the `label` from props will can do this `[{ props: { label } }]`

```js
const children = [{
    props: {
      label: 'Some label'
    }
  },
  {
    props: {
      label: 'Second label'
    }
  },

  ,
  {
    props: {
      label: 'another label'
    }
  }]
  
  const [{ props: { label } }] = children;
  
  console.log(label);
```

**With complex data**

```js
const children = [{
    props: {
      label: [{
        data: {
          title: 'complex destructor'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          title: 'complex destructor 2'
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    props: {
      label: 'Second label'
    }
  },

  ,
  {
    props: {
      label: 'another label'
    }
  }]

 const [{ props: { label: [ { data: { title } } ] } }] = children;

console.log(title)
```