# How can I implement destructuring assignment for functional react components props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm trying to pass functional component props by **destructuring assignment** method.

In this example below I have tried to use this concept but it doesn't work.
the result of this code return empty and doesn't print that prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = ({ username: name }) => (<h1>{username}</h1>)

render(
   <App name="Tom" />,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Any ideas on how to handle this issue ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your're passing prop from **App** as ***name*** not ***username***

change this

```
const App = ({ username : name })
```

to this

```
const App = ({ name: username })
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = ({ name: username }) => (<h1>{username}</h1>)

render(
   <App name="Tom" />,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Tnx it's working now. why is it filled the name and username values in some kind of opossit syntax?

Comment: @SalarBahador the syntax is `{ propertyName : reference variable }` you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses/54605288#54605288) for more info

Comment: So this structure is different than other object structures in javascript? in the usual way, we say define object like :  `obj = { key : value }`

Comment: @SalarBahador here you're not defining a object  you're picking values from object