# Produce Object from Array of Two Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to figure out how to take an array of two objects and merge them into a single object.

First off, here's what I did to produce my combined array from two arrays:

```
let p;
let v;
let combinedArray = [];

for (let diff of differences) {
  for (let mapping of mappings) {
    if (diff.path[0] === mapping.rhs) {
      p = diff.path[0];
      v = diff.rhs;
      combinedArray.push({ p, v });
    }
  }
}
```

The resulting combined array looks like this:

```
[ { p: 'prop_1', v: 'x1' },
  { p: 'prop_2', v: 'x2' } ]
```

What I need to do next is create a final object that looks like this:

```
{ 'prop_1': 'x1', 'prop_2': 'x2' }
```

How can I do that from the results of my "combined" array above? And, by the way, if there's a simpler way to do this from the outset of my initial two arrays I'm all for it. Open to suggestions here.

Comment: So why not replace `combinedArray.push({ p, v });` with `combinedObject[p] = v`?

Comment: you forget to provide `differences` and `mappings`

Comment: @trincot, that makes a lot of sense. That really reduces the coded needed to produce the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would skip creating the `combinedArray` and go immediately for the target object structure. Replace:

```
combinedArray.push({ p, v });
```

with:

```
combinedObject[p] = v
```

Obviously you would initialise `combinedObject` as `{}`.

Now if you really want to convert `combinedArray` to a plain object, then [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) is your friend:

```js
const combinedArray = [{ p: 'prop_1', v: 'x1' }, { p: 'prop_2', v: 'x2' }];
  
const combinedObject = Object.fromEntries(combinedArray.map(({p, v}) => [p, v]));

console.log(combinedObject);
```

It would have been easier if your `combinedArray` already consisted of pairs. So you would have done `combinedArray.push([p, v])`. In that case you only need `Object.fromEntries(combinedArray)`.

Comment: Thanks, the first of these two options works perfectly, and is definitely the most succinct of the options available to produce the result I need in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

change your combinedArray to object and use like this

```
combinedArray[p] = v
```

in case you need both the structures you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`destructuring`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses) further on your current output

```js
let data = [ { p: 'prop_1', v: 'x1' },
  { p: 'prop_2', v: 'x2' } ]
  
let final = data.reduce((op,{p,v}) => {
  op[p] = v
  return op
},{})

console.log(final)
```