# Can someone please explain me this: 'create({email: emailArg} = {}) {}'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo

I'm still learning JS. Doing Apollo GraphQL tutorial: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/introduction/

And I don't quite understand this part: `findOrCreateUser({ email: emailArg } = {})`

Full code below:

```
   /**
   * User can be called with an argument that includes email, but it doesn't
   * have to be. If the user is already on the context, it will use that user
   * instead
   */
  async findOrCreateUser({ email: emailArg } = {}) {
    const email =
      this.context && this.context.user ? this.context.user.email : emailArg;
    if (!email || !isEmail.validate(email)) return null;

    const users = await this.store.users.findOrCreate({ where: { email } });
    return users && users[0] ? users[0] : null;
  }

  async bookTrips({ launchIds }) {
    const userId = this.context.user.id;
    if (!userId) return;

    let results = [];

    // for each launch id, try to book the trip and add it to the results array
    // if successful
    for (const launchId of launchIds) {
      const res = await this.bookTrip({ launchId });
      if (res) results.push(res);
    }

    return results;
  }
```

Please educate me or a link to explanation will be fine. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is destructuring assignment and its uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

Comment: From MDN: [Setting a function parameter's default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameter's_default_value)

Comment: Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/e374v2h0/

Comment: So, it basically does like `findOrCreateUser({ email: emailArg })`? Then what's the point of adding `= {}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
findOrCreateUser({ email: emailArg } = {})
```

is the combination of several principles

**1) Object destructuring**

```
const { prop } = obj;
```

is equivalent to:

```
const prop = obj.prop;
```

**2) Function Arguments destructuring**

Same thing but for the arguments of a function

```
function fun({ prop }) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
function fun(obj) {
  console.log(obj.prop);
}
```

**3) Renaming variable when destructuring**

```
function fun({ prop: newPropName }) {
  console.log(newPropName);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
function fun(obj) {
  const newPropName = obj.prop;
  console.log(newPropName);
}
```

**4) Default function parameter**

```
function fun(arg = 5) {
  console.log(arg); 
}

fun(10); // prints 10
fun(); // prints 5 since no value was passed to fun
```

**Conclusion:**

```
findOrCreateUser({ email: emailArg } = {}) {
 // [...]
}
```

is the equivalent of

```
findOrCreateUser(args) {
  const emailArg = args ? args.email : {};
  // [...]
}
```

In other words, it renames the `email` property of the object passed to the method to `emailArg` and makes it directly available. It also intializes the arguments to an empty object if nothing is passed to the function. This is to avoid provoking a `Cannot read email of undefined` if nothing is passed.

Here are the docs if you need more context:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

Answer (score 1):

I think that:

1) The function expects to receive as its first argument a JavaScript Object that has inside it a property called `email`
2) Inside the function, we will refer to that `email` property as `emailArg`

Finally, the `= {}` part provides an empty object as the default value, helping to avoid errors.

---

A more detailed explanation of destructuring of function arguments can be found here: https://davidwalsh.name/destructuring-function-arguments