# How to return an array without duplicate items within array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, reduce

I have an array with multiples of certain automobiles, included within it. I am trying to return an array with one of every item, without duplicates.

I have a functioning piece of code, using an `if...else` format, but cannot achieve the same result with a conditional statement, in JavaScript. It says that `list.includes(automobile)` is not a function.

```js
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck'];
let noDuplicates = data.reduce((list, automobile) => {
  if (list.includes(automobile)) {
    return list
  } else {
    return [...list, automobile]
  }
}, []);

console.log(noDuplicates)
```

This version with `if...else`, works, but where I'm struggling to achieve the same result is with a conditional statement, like the following:

```js
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck'];
let noDuplicates = data.reduce((list, automobile) => {
   list.includes[automobile] ? list : [...list, automobile]
}, []);

console.log(noDuplicates)
```

I assume I may have some parenthesis missing, or in the wrong place, but it appears correct to me. The `if...else` statement returned exactly what I was looking for, `["car", "truck", "bike", "walk", "van"]`, but the conditional statement was not.

Answer (score 4):

> Why my code is not working ?

- Missing `return` statement
- `list.includes[automobile]` this should be `list.includes(automobile)`

```js
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck'];
let noDuplicates = data.reduce((list, automobile) => {
   return list.includes(automobile) ? list : [...list, automobile]
}, []);

console.log(noDuplicates)
```

---

You can simply use `Set`

```js
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck' ];
let unique = [...new Set(data)]

console.log(unique)
```

Comment: Also Why `...` is getting ***unexpected token*** without `[]` ?

Comment: @hs-dev2MR `[...]` to get values from Set, you can read here [`Set MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), `...` without `[]` is invalid syntax [`Destructuring`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

Comment: Okay I got it ! I love u now