# How to merge duplicate values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects and I have duplicated value on it and I want to merge all duration who have been created in the same date and who have the same file Name

Thank You In Advance :)

I have array of objects

```
[
    {
    fileName: "test.js"
    duration: 1500,
    createt_at: "2019-07-26T09:57:28.126Z"
    },
    {
    fileName: "test.js"
    duration: 1500,
    createt_at: "2019-07-26T10:00:28.126Z"
    },
    {
    fileName: "test.js"
    duration: 1500,
    createt_at: "2019-07-26T09:57:28.126Z"
    },
    {
    fileName: "main.js"
    duration: 1500,
    createt_at: "2019-07-26T09:57:28.126Z"
    },
    {
    fileName: "main.js"
    duration: 3000,
    createt_at: "2019-07-28T10:57:28.126Z"
    },
    {
    fileName: "main.js"
    duration: 2000,
    createt_at: "2019-07-28T11:00:28.126Z"
    }
    {
    fileName: "main.js"
    duration: 100,
    createt_at: "2019-07-28T09:00:28.126Z"
    }
]
```

**Output Array Of Objects Need To Be Like This :**

```
[
    {
    fileName: "test.js"
    duration: 3000,
    createt_at: "2019-07-26"
    },
    {
    fileName: "main.js"
    duration: 1500,
    createt_at: "2019-07-26"
    },
    {
    fileName: "main.js"
    duration: 5100,
    createt_at: "2019-07-28"
    }
]
```

Comment: You should try to use reduce on your array. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @quino I tried to filter and reduce array but I didn't get what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `fileName and date` as combined key and add duration accordingly

- Loop through array, check if combined key is present on Map or not
- If not present initialize it with current element's value,
- If already present then add duration of current element with the value of particular key

```js
let data = [{fileName: "test.js",duration: 1500,createt_at: "2019-07-26T09:57:28.126Z"},{fileName: "test.js",duration: 1500,createt_at: "2019-07-26T10:00:28.126Z"},{fileName: "test.js",duration: 1500,createt_at: "2019-07-26T09:57:28.126Z"},{fileName: "main.js",duration: 1500,createt_at: "2019-07-26T09:57:28.126Z"},{fileName: "main.js",duration: 3000,createt_at: "2019-07-28T10:57:28.126Z"},{fileName: "main.js",duration: 2000,createt_at: "2019-07-28T11:00:28.126Z"}, {fileName: "main.js",duration: 100,createt_at: "2019-07-28T09:00:28.126Z"}]


let op = data.reduce((op,inp) => {
  let {fileName,createt_at} = inp
  let date = createt_at.substring(0,10)
  let key = fileName+date
  if(op.has(key)){
    let val = op.get(key)
    val.duration += inp.duration
  } else {
    op.set(key,inp)
  }
  return op
},new Map())

console.log([...op.values()])
```

Comment: Nice! Could you please explain the meaning of `let {fileName,createt_at} = inp`?

Comment: @RezaSaadati thanks, this is called [`destructuring`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses), i am using this to take `fileName and createt_at` properties form object

Comment: Great, I din't know about that. Thank you!