# How to understand destructuring syntax in following codes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I found some codes when reading a article. And i can't understand it. But when i tested it, it worked! can anyone told me what is parameter means? it is a destructuring?

```js
function test ({ a = '1', b = '2', c = '3' } ={}) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
};
test();  //> "1" "2" "3"
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at: [What is destructuring assignment and its uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54605286)

Answer (score 1):

Here default values for properties are set: `{ a = '1', b = '2', c = '3' }`.
As soon as no value is passed to `test()` - default value `{}` is used. It doesn't have those properties `a`, `b`, `c` - so resulted variables get default values.

In case you pass some object with existing known properties - their values will be used:

```js
function test ({ a = '1', b = '2', c = '3' } ={}) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
};
test();  //> "1" "2" "3"

test({a: 10});  //> "10" "2" "3"
```

You can read more about destructuring on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I get it now.

1, { a = '1', b = '2', c = '3' } : object {a,b,c} have default values '1','2','3'.

2, {}: this is default parameter.

3, { a = '1', b = '2', c = '3' }={} : it will destructure the parameter to object {a,b,c}. then get values of variables a,b,c

thanks falinsky.