# When declaring a function component with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-state, react-functional-component

So I have seen people using different ways to declare a function. However, I saw one way that I did not quite understand. The sample code is shown as below:

```
type Props = { 
    name: string,
    age: number
}

const someFunction = ({
    name,
    age
}: Props) => {
   return (
    // Do something here
   )
}
```

So I know this code here is first creating a Props object with name and age. The part that I do not get is the part where it shows `({name, age}: Props)`. I am guessing it is a parameter mapping the state to the props, but I am not sure. Can anyone explain this please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is destructuring assignment and its uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It is an ES6 syntax.

It exists for [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

It is basically a way to extract part of an array/object.

When doing `{ name, age } = props`, you're *extracting* `name` and `age` from the usually called `props` object.

**Using destructuring:**

```js
const someFunction = ({
    name,
    age
}: Props) => {
  console.log(name, age)
}
```

**Without destructuring:**

```js
const someFunction = (props: Props) => {
  const name = props.name
  const age = props.age

  console.log(name, age)  
}
```

Comment: So if I have something like ({"Andy", 10}: Props) it is going to pass it to name = "Andy", age = 10?

Comment: I edited the examples. It is not a way to *assign* values, it is only a shortcut, to avoid having to repeat yourself as in `const name = props.name`. You can simply say: `const { name } = props`.

Comment: That made sense now. Thanks a lot