# What is this spread statement supposed to do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've gotten rusty on Redux, and did not comment my code well.  I looked in the console using console.log and I can't figure out what is going on.

I also looked at a [cheat sheet](https://devhints.io/es6#spread) here.

I've removed other cases to simplify the concerns.

```
const Articles = (state, action) => {
  
  console.log('state', state);
  let newState = { ...state };          // here?
  console.log('newState', newState);

  switch(action.type) {
    case "updateArticles":
      newState.articles = action.articles;
      break;
  }
  return newState;
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses

Answer (score 1):

This statement `let newState = { ...state };` will clone the object into a new one. This is helpful to make sure you don't manipulate the old one by just doing `let newState = state;` and just passing the reference.

Answer (score 1):

In React (and redux), state should never be mutated, because React uses `Object.is` to determine whether a stateful value has changed (and if it doesn't detect a change, re-rendering will be skipped).

What you have there isn't destructuring, but *spread syntax* - you're creating a shallow copy of the `state` object and putting the copy into a variable named `newState`. This means that setting the new state to `newState` will result in re-rendering.

If you had mutated the old state instead by using the `state` variable instead of a new `newState` variable, you might well have not seen a re-render.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log - you're populating it afterwards

Comment: I don't like it. I'd clone inside the cases when necessary instead.

Comment: It's not that it's not efficient (though I guess it's not), it's that it's not a very pure approach - better to create and return a new object only when you *need* to return a new object, rather than create one in advance and mutate it.

Comment: I saw the unaccept, was there something that's still confusing you?