# What is "data:" in try block of below code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I knew that in try block {data} is response data, but cannot understand what is data: in code. Here I am making a travel advisor which gives you your location's restaurants. For that I am using rapidapi.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const getPlacesData = async (type, sw, ne) => {
//Here in try, axios call api and get response
  try {
  //I am asking about below const{data:....}
    const { data: { data } } = await axios.get(`https://travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com/${type}/list-in-boundary`, {

      params: {

        bl_latitude: sw.lat,

        bl_longitude: sw.lng,

        tr_longitude: ne.lng,

        tr_latitude: ne.lat,

      },

      headers: {

        'x-rapidapi-key': process.env.REACT_APP_RAPID_API_TRAVEL_API_KEY,

        'x-rapidapi-host': 'travel-advisor.p.rapidapi.com',

      },

    });
   //It returns desired data
    return data;

  } catch (error) {
   //It console log error if  any error
    console.log(error);

  }

};
```

What's data:? What's the purpose to use that data:?

Comment: It is called Object destructuring. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses

Comment: I knew it that {data} is destructing but they use data:{data} what is the data:?

Comment: The innermost data is what they want and it is nested inside  'outer' `data` key in the response object.

Comment: "data:" is the outer data and property of axios??  What is the purpose of it?

Comment: ... `response.data.data` is what you want to retrieve. They just extracted the innermost key `data` by doing `{data:{data}}`. It has nothing to do with axios itself  and everything to do with destructuring

Comment: But when I hover data: it shows axios property?

Comment: I dont understand the confusion you are having... So it is an axios property. It doesn't change why restructuring is used here

Comment: That's why I didn't understand

Comment: Axios data property

Comment: https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema

Comment: Means data:{} is axios property which is received response from api?

Comment: yes.. Its there in the scheme