# React: Get route param when using render method in routing

Tags: react-router, react-apollo

I've currently changed my routing around a bit to support certain routes having different, arbitrary layouts. The scheme works on all views other than when I need to pass a value via route to the component. For example, I have the following route defined:

```
function renderWithLayout(Component, Layout) {
    return <Layout><Component /></Layout>
}

export default class App extends Component {
    displayName = App.name;
    render() {
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
              <Route 
              path="/articles/view/:id"
              render={() => renderWithLayout(ArticlesView, PublicLayout)}
              exact={true}
              />
        </ApolloProvider>
    }
}
```

then in my ArticlesView component, I am attempting to grab the `id` passed to the route as follows in the `render()` method:

```
const { match: params } = this.props;
console.log(params); //this is undefined
var id = params.id; //TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

before I changed the routing around, I could just do `const { id } = this.props.match.params;`

how can I overcome this issue?

EDIT: before the routing change, I had the route defined as:

```
<Route 
    path="/articles/view/:id"
    component={ArticlesView}
    exact={true}
    />
```

Comment: You need to spread the route props. `render={(props) => renderWithLayout(ArticlesView, PublicLayout, props)}` and then `function renderWithLayout(Component, Layout, props) { return <Layout><Component {...props} /></Layout> }`

Comment: that works thanks. If you'd like to elaborate on this answer (particulary the `...props` part) and post as an answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/31048953 - Basically React Router exposes the props you want as an argument. To pass that down to your route component, you need to explicitly pass it down and spread them.

Comment: @GregH you can also use `withRouter(ArticlesView)` HOC provided by react-router.