# Why do I keep getting an array inside an array when using push()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6

I am trying to understand MDN's documentation on [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) because I'm having an issue where I am ending up with an array inside an array in a project. I have set up some experimental code to illustrate my problem.

Can anyone explain why the array contents inside `foo()` print within another array? I am not understanding why it isn't printing one array for both `console.log()`instances.

```
var animals = [];
var chickens = 'chickens';
var cows = 'cows';

animals.push(cows);
animals.push(chickens);

console.log(animals); // > Array ["cows", "chickens"]

function foo(...animals) {
  console.log(animals); // > Array [["cows", "chickens"]] <-- why is this one inside another array?
};
```

I thought using `.apply()` would solve the problem but it I couldn't get it to work. For example...

```
animals.push.apply(animals, cows);
animals.push.apply(animals, chickens);

// Error: second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an array
```

Comment: Thats what `...` does.. in the same way as just using `arguments` its going to be an array, so you passed in one argument it will be in `animals[0]` which is the value you passed in, pass in 2 your see 2 elements.

Comment: This is what `...` spread/rest operator does. Check details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do/54968890#54968890

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `...` (rest/spread syntax) makes a new array out of the passed arguments - so making an array out of `["chickens", "cows"]` will result in `[["chickens", "cows"]]`. Solve this by removing the `...` in `foo`.

```js
var animals = [];
var chickens = 'chickens';
var cows = 'cows';

animals.push(cows);
animals.push(chickens);

console.log(animals); 

function foo(animals) {
  console.log(animals); 
}; 

foo(animals);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Also, naming the function parameter the same as the global variable can cause confusion.

Comment: Yes @Derek, however it will always work because JavaScript looks for variables with the same name in the current scope first before moving outwards one layer - so local variables in a function would take precedence over global variables of the same name.

Comment: Yes, simply called as "Variable Shadowing". But in any case, @Derek is right, naming the parameter the same as a variable will surely lead to confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Read about this `->` [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#Description)

```js
// "Rest parameters" receives the arguments which is 
// a like array object, and uses its indexes for creating an array.
function fn(...params) {
  console.log(params);
} 

fn("Ele", "From", "Stack"); // Multiple params will be spread as indexes of the array.
fn(["Ele", "From", "Stack"]); // In this case, one param (an array) will be used as the only index in the array.
fn(); // In this case, an empty array will be generated.
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

On the other hand, the function `apply`, the second param should be an array which depicts the arguments

```
Array.push.apply(animals, [cows, chickens]);
```