# What does const myObject = { ...object1, ...object2 } evaluate to in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, operators

I inherited some code in a React Native codebase and was just curious as to what this syntax means. Can't seem to find a good answer by googling but I have console logged it seems like:

```
   const myObject = object2 ? ojbect2 : object1
```

Is similar to:

```
   const myObject = { ...object1, ...object2}
```

Comment: spread syntax..

Comment: Not similar at all.

Comment: ^ [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54968890/3082296) from the duplicate specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `const myObject = { ...object1, ...object2}` is called *combination of properties from objects using `spread sysntax`*, so you can create objects using the attributes from multiple objects.

For example, the following example illustrates how the function `Object.assign` and spread syntax are related.

*Spread syntax*

```js
let object1 = {
  "name": "Ele"
};

let object2 = {
  "from": "Stack"
};

const myObject = { ...object1, ...object2};
// Now myObject is a combination of the previous objects.
console.log(myObject);
```

`Object.assign`

```js
let object1 = {
  "name": "Ele"
};

let object2 = {
  "from": "Stack"
};

const myObject = Object.assign({}, object1, object2);
// Now myObject is a combination of the previous objects.
console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score -1):

The first is logical operators.

`const myObject = object2 ? ojbect2 : object1`

Which is equivalent to:

`const myObject = ()=>{if(object2){return object2}else{return object1}}`

For the other, spread syntax, [see this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for a description of how that works.
It's supposed to be used for expanding objects inline to be passed to any other object/function.

Comment: I think you mean: `if(object2){return object2} else {return object1}`. And that's not syntactically correct.  It needs to be in a block for ternary for the `else` to work.