# What does spread operator outside of curly braces do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This comes from my React project, and is something I’ve never seen before:

```
const { list, loading, failed } = this.props
return <ExperienceList {…{ list, loading, failed }} />
```

Specifically, I’m referring to the spread operator OUTSIDE of the curly braces. I’m used to seeing them inside.

Comment: Probably it means: 1) pick only those 3 keys from the original props and then 2) do the spreading as usual, i.e. apply those 3 props to the compoment. IMHO

Comment: You are deconstructing the object into another object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do these three dots in React do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do)

Comment: not a duplicate; my question is related to how it works when the '...' is preceded by an object

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example

```
return <ExperienceList {…{ list, loading, failed }} />
```

is equivalent to

```
return <ExperienceList {…this.props} />
```

it does the same thing, which is

```
return <ExperienceList list={list} loading={loading} failed={failed} />
```

Comment: note it's only strictly equivalent to `...this.props` if `this.props` only contains those three keys

Comment: yeah, making the assumption that `this.props == { list, loading, failed }` in this case

Comment: so what is the real benefit of writing it this way?

Comment: the only one I can think is that `this.props` may have many props, but you want to forward only three of them.