# why I can not use function keyword to define a function inside a reactjs class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been confused about some syntaxes in ReactJS, one is that when I define a function inside one Reactjs class, I can not use function keyword, but when I moved the function outside the class then I have to add keyword function before the signature. Second is that if I write a function inside the render(), then I have to use arrow function. For example, why the following is wrong:

```
class Test extends Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props)
   }
   function test(){
     //this is wrong,I need to remove function keyword
   }

   render(){
     mytest(){
      //also this is wrong,I only can use arrow function
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Because this is a class body and it expects to have *methods*. It's not allowed by the syntax of JS but also it doesn't have semantic sense - a function shouldn't have its own context, yet it will be bound to the class itself.

Comment: Note that this is not a React thing; it's basic JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @VLAZ if possible , can you please provide any javascript docs or references to support your answer. it will be helpful

Comment: @vijaykiranreddy https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-definitions https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-class-definitions https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-method-definitions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do/47944283#47944283
@VLAZ , can you pls help me with my doubt in the above link

Answer (score 17):

That's because your component is class based and has methods, not functions. To define a method you can do like so:

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  test() { // Defining method

  }

  render() {
    this.test() // can be called like this
  }
}
```

If you want to be able to define functions inside a component you'll need to transform it to functional first:

```
function Test(props) {
  function test() {
    // This now works
  }
}
```

Comment: Just quickly want to add that it is also possible to use arrow functions in functional components. As in `const test = () => { // this now works }`

Comment: @Julian, but without the `const` part :)

Comment: @devserkan No, the `const` part is needed :)

Comment: It's possible to have both arrow functions in functional and methods in class based components.

Comment: @Clarity Sure! With the example of arrow functions I was referring to `functional components`. devserkan meant classes, I meant functional components, both possible `const` is the difference

Comment: Ah, I missed the "functional components" part. My bad @Julian :)