# How can i add object into another object in javascript after fetching data from API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const fetchData = Object { data: [], status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: {} }
```

How do i add below object into above fetchdata.data object

```
const priceModel = {id:1, name:"abc"}
```

result should be like below

```
const fetchData = Object { data: {[], priceModel:{id:1, name:"abc"}}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: {} }
```

Comment: `mergedObject = {...fetchData, priceModel}`

Comment: this way i can add into fetchData.data ?

Comment: @shabeeb_ck : no, above will return you the *new object* which will have all the properties of `fetchData` and `priceModel` property that will hold corresponding object. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: ```mergedObject = {...fetchData, priceModel}``` . Here triple dot is a spread syntax. For More info [refer this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do) or [this blog](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-the-spread-syntax-f5c35525f754)

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment above mentions you can use the spread operator if you want to add it as a key in the main object.

If you want to assign it into data then you can simply

```
fetchData.data= {data:fetchData.data, priceModel}
```

This will keep the data array as you had it. 
if you want to merge priceModel into the data, given that you have shown data as an array, you can

```
fetchData.data.push({priceModel})
```

Hope this helps!