# JS create array with arrow function and rest parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

In one app I saw this part of code:

```
const arrayCreate = length => [...Array(length)];
```

It works, but I'm not sure how. We have a arrow function that takes a length parameter, and creates an array in array or what? :)
And what does the spread operator doing here?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do these three dots in React do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do)

Comment: `arrayCreate(length)` is a round about way of doing `Array(length)`. In both cases you will end up with an array of length `length`, being filled with `null`s.

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413445/4642212) explains it. That’s not a very useful function, though, as it fills the array with `undefined` (not `null`, and it’s not equivalent to `Array(length)` which isn’t filled at all, @cars10m). A more useful way of creating an array that is filled with _something_ actionable is the expression [`Array.from({ length:` _someLength_ `}, (_, index) =>` _someFunctionOfIndex_ `)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Answer (score 1):

`Array(length)` will create an array of `length` empty slots, for which, though, you cannot map or iterate using array methods like `.map` `.forEach` etc.

When you spread (*`...`*) the array with the empty slots it will create a new array with `undefined` for each array position. So you can now `.map` and `.forEach` because they are not empty slots.

So this is a way to create an array of `length` filled with `undefined`.

You could do the same with

```
Array(length).fill()
```

or

```
Array.from(Array(length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! The developer who made this probably wanted to optimize the performance at writing a first value at index or to be able to iterate through the empty values

An array is a javascript object that have:

- key/value pairs assigned to respectively array's index/ value at index
- length (size of the array)
- prototype (getters, setters, array methods...)

`Array(length)` or `new Array(length)` returns `{ length: 0, prototype: {} }`. The object is empty, with the length equals to passed in `length`

Now `[...Array(length)]` will return `{ 0: undefined, 1: undefined, 2: undefined: 3: undefined, 4: undefined, 5: undefined, length: 5, prototype: {} }`. The properties are now allocated to their `undefined` values

Answer (score 0):

@Gabrielse's post answers the question pretty well. However, there's just one more thing that I'd like to add to it.

One use-case where you might do **something like** this is when you have a `set` iterable and you want its elements inside an array. for e.g.

```
const set = new Set();
set.add('foo');
set.add('bar');
set.add('baz');
```

Suppose, you've the items `foo`, `bar`, `baz` in a set. A simple `console.log(set);` would result `Set { 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' }`. The result you get of course is a set. But what if you want these items in an array?

A simple way to do this would be to use `...`(spread operator) applied to the `set` inside an array. The result of `console.log([...set]);` would be `[ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ]`.