# react router private route implementation is path props passed or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hello everyone this is more of a request asking review on my understanding of private route implementation in react.js rather than a question. Many implementations of private routes with authentication seem to have this same code posted

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
)
```

now as far as I know the 3 dots is the spread operator which basically assigns the passed object . Further SO answer also corroborates it [What do these three dots in React do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do) especially the answer from Mehdi Raash . Now my understanding is that this basically means that the 'path' prop is also passed in the ...rest object just like

```
<Route path={rest.path} render={(props) => (
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true
          ? <Component {...props} />
          : <Redirect to='/login' />
      )} />
```

but recently i have came across this post https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-protected-routes-authentication/
and this line just doesn't make sense to me

```
A few notes on the above code. With Route, if a path isn’t supplied, then that Route will always match. So in the case above, because we didn’t supply a path prop, the Route will always match which means the render prop will always be called.
```

So I just want to know whether this statement is correct and path props isn't being passed in the private route implementation and if so then what is this {...rest} doing in the Route.

Note: No offence for the author behind the article i just want my understanding stand corrected if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

The [spread operator](https://codeburst.io/a-simple-guide-to-destructuring-and-es6-spread-operator-e02212af5831) basically puts all remaining properties into a new object called `rest` in your case. Let's say that **PrivateRoute** was initiated like this:

```
<PrivateRoute component={Home} path="/protected" secure={false} />
```

`component` was desctructured and renamed to `Component` in your example. This means that `rest` looks like this:

```
rest = {
  path: "/protected",
  secure: false
}
```

What happens next is that the `rest` object is spreaded into the **Route**. So this:

```
<Route {...rest} render={(props) => ()} />
```

is the same as this:

```
<Route path={res.path} secure={res.secure} render={(props) => ()} />
```

or this:

```
<Route path="/protected" secure={false} render={(props) => ()} />
```

By the way, the props in the `render()` function only contain [three props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) and they come from the Router:

- match
- location
- history

Comment: thanks for your answer basically you are also establishing the fact that path props do get passed on to the Route.